# How to format string variable to date with specific format?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, fullcalendar, date-formatting

I need help with my case. I'm new to JS.
I get the value (10/19/2016) from current page and try to create the Date object.
But if the date is (19/10/2016) it gives me an NaN page.
I need something like that format(MyVar, "dd/mm/yy") at anytime the variable was.
How can it be done, i'm really stuck on this.

```
<link href="{!$Resource.fullCalendarCSS}" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="{!$Resource.fullCalendarPrintCSS}" rel="stylesheet" media="print" />

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script src="{!$Resource.JqueryDateFormatJS}"></script>
<script src="{!$Resource.JqueryDateFormatMinJS}"></script>
<script src="{!$Resource.DateFormatJS}"></script>
<script src="{!$Resource.DateFormatMinJS}"></script>
<script src="{!$Resource.fullCalendarMinJS}"></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>

     $.noConflict();
     jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        tempValue = '{!$CurrentPage.parameters.startDate}';



        newDate1 = $.datepicker.formatDate("mm/dd/yy", new Date(tempValue));
        console.log(newDate1);
        newDate = new Date(newDate1);
        console.log(newDate);



        d = newDate.getDate();
        m = newDate.getMonth();
        y = newDate.getFullYear();           

    //We need to wrap everything in a doc.ready function so that the code fires after the DOM is loaded 
    //Call the fullCallendar method. You can replace the '#calendar' with the ID of the dom element where you want the calendar to go. 
        jQuery('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            year: y,
            month: m,
            date: d,                                                   
            defaultView: 'agendaDay',
            slotMinutes: 15,
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            editable: false,
            events:
            [
                //At run time, this APEX Repeat will reneder the array elements for the events array
                <apex:repeat value="{!events}" var="e">
                    {
                        title: "{!e.title}",
                        start: '{!e.startString}',
                        end: '{!e.endString}',
                        url: '{!e.url}',
                        allDay: {!e.allDay},
                        className: '{!e.className}',
                    },
                </apex:repeat>
            ]
        });           
    });    
</script>
```

I'm using fullCalendar and DateFormat plugin.

if my variable tempValue in the format "mm/dd/yy" i can define the date object like:

```
date = new Date(tempVal) ----> Thu Oct 20 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (Russia TZ 2 Standard Time)
```

and if vy variable will be in the format "dd/mm/yy" it gives me the th error "Invalid date".

I need to get tempValue only in the format "mm/dd/yy" even if it comes in the format "dd/mm/yy".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse DateTime string in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1576753/parse-datetime-string-in-javascript)

Comment: OP need date parts splitted anyway, for FullCallendar.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript `Date()` expects [a couple date string formats](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_formats.asp)...
But not dd/mm/yyyy.

You noticed that.

So, since you already have a correct date from date picker, why not simply [`.split`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) it to retreive parts?

If you want to perform calculation on dates, like finding the difference between two dates, then use these splitted parts to pass a correct format to `Date()`.

```js
// Commented out because we don't have this value here in this snippet.
//tempValue = '{!$CurrentPage.parameters.startDate}';

// I used this date value instead...
tempValue = "24/09/2016";

console.log(tempValue);

//newDate1 = $.datepicker.formatDate("mm/dd/yy", new Date(tempValue));
//console.log(newDate1);
//newDate = new Date(newDate1);

// Get the splitted values
var dateTemp = tempValue.split("/");

d = dateTemp[0];
m = dateTemp[1];
y = dateTemp[2];

console.log("d: " + d);
console.log("m: " + m);
console.log("y: " + y);

// To perform calculations, you'll need this.
calcDate1 = new Date(m + "/" + d + "/" + y);
console.log(calcDate1.toString());
```

```html
Just run the snippet and check the console...<br>
;)
```

Comment: You can also use this really easy and popular library http://momentjs.com/

Comment: @Louys Thanks for answer!

Comment: @Louys, It doesn't resolved my problem( the variable tempValue could be an "24/10/2016" or "10/24/2016" so if a d var will be 24 the new Date will give me an error "Invalid day". I need to format any of date format in the only one format "mm/dd/yy". How can i do that?

Comment: Well, you have to find a way to use only one of the two formats... **OR** to use a flag to tell the script which format is used in order to bypass the month/day inversion when needed. For Javascript, both day and month are `integer`... It can't see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

So finally i have found the solution...
The exact problem was in the User locale, so the user with locale English (Inited states) have a 'M/d/yyyy' date format, so we need to write the code to create the Date object for every Locale date format.

And finally:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

     $.noConflict();
     jQuery(document).ready(function() {

        tempValue = '{!$CurrentPage.parameters.startDate}';

        var userLang = UserContext.dateFormat;
        var dateTemp = tempValue.split("/");

        d1 = dateTemp[0];
        m1 = dateTemp[1];
        y1 = dateTemp[2];

        y='';
        d='';
        m='';      

        console.log(userLang);     

        if (userLang === "M/d/yyyy") {                           

            newDate = new Date(d1 + "/" + m1 + "/" + y1);
            d = newDate.getDate();
            m = newDate.getMonth();
            y = newDate.getFullYear();                                                                                               
        };

        if (userLang === "dd/MM/yyyy") {                           

            newDate = new Date(m1 + "/" + d1 + "/" + y1);
            d = newDate.getDate();
            m = newDate.getMonth();
            y = newDate.getFullYear();                                                                                               
        };            


    //We need to wrap everything in a doc.ready function so that the code fires after the DOM is loaded 
    //Call the fullCallendar method. You can replace the '#calendar' with the ID of the dom element where you want the calendar to go. 
        jQuery('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            year: y,
            month: m,
            date: d,                                                   
            defaultView: 'agendaDay',
            slotMinutes: 15,
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            editable: false,
            events:
            [
                //At run time, this APEX Repeat will reneder the array elements for the events array
                <apex:repeat value="{!events}" var="e">
                    {
                        title: "{!e.title}",
                        start: '{!e.startString}',
                        end: '{!e.endString}',
                        url: '{!e.url}',
                        allDay: {!e.allDay},
                        className: '{!e.className}',
                    },
                </apex:repeat>
            ]
        });           
    });    
</script>
```

I think this is not the best solution, but if you have some idea for that, please tell me.

Thanks!