# take a date string, add a class to span if expiration date is less than 2 weeks from now

Tags: javascript, jquery

i've been stuck on this problem for a while now and I am ready to pull my hair out :). I have to add a class to a span if a campaign date is expiring in 2 weeks or less. The date retrieved is a string in the following format

07/26/2017

when I run this function, I am passing the datestring as an argument since the method will be attached to the var which holds the string. But for whatever reason this logic isn't working. Am I totally screwing this up?  It's failing silently somewhere. Thank you. I know it should be easy but I am caught in a loop.

```
campMethods.EndDateAlert = function (dateString) {
    var currentDate = new Date ();
    var twoWeeks = new Date ();
    twoWeeks.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 14)
    var $EndDateSpan = $('.campaign-end-date');

    if (dateString <= twoWeeks) { 
        $EndDateSpan.addClass('red');
  }
    return dateString;
};
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare two dates with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript)

Comment: Also [Parse DateTime string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1576753/215552) for the first part.

Comment: check my answer below :) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with some Math. The key is, 2 weeks = 14 days.

Here is Pure Javascript example for you:

```js
var date = "07/26/2017".split("/");
var formatedDate = (date[2] + '' + date[0] + '' + date[1]);


var currentDate = new Date();

var today = currentDate.getFullYear() +''+ ("0" + (currentDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2)+''+("0" + currentDate.getDate()).slice(-2); 

var compareDay = formatedDate - today;


if(compareDay < 14){// 14 day = 2 week
// do something for less than 2 weeks
console.log('Less than 2 weeks will be expired');
} else {
// also can do something
console.log('more than 2 weeks will be expired.');
}
```

[Javascript Date Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Try comparing milliseconds of the dates.
We know that there are 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 14 = 1209600000 milliseconds in two weeks, knowing this we can add 1209600000ms to the current date and compare this to the milliseconds of the due date.

```
let dueDate = new Date('07/26/2017');

if(Date.now() + 1209600000 > dueDate.getMilliseconds()){
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: `getMilliseconds()` returns the number of milliseconds in the current time. You want `getTime()`. But this is also the answer from the proposed duplicate, so you're not doing yourself any favors by answering it.