# How to make a javascript timer that when time is greater than 60 it converts to minutes and seconds

Tags: javascript, function, timer

```
function countdown()
{
    seconds = 1000;
    delay = delay-seconds;
    conversion = Math.ceil(delay / seconds );
    document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML =  conversion + ":seconds until alarm goes off";
    t3 = setTimeout("countdown()",1000);

    if(conversion == 0)
    {
        alert('Wake UP!!!');
        DontDoIt();
    }
}
```

This code displays the timer in seconds. I want to be able to show the time in minutes and seconds if the time is greater than 60.

I want to be able to do this with hours, minutes, and seconds

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do, but this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sqn8X/) show a simple countdown, maybe that helps you out ?

Comment: i want the count down to show min:seconds if seconds is greater than 60

Comment: Good for you, then all you have to do is add `if (seconds>60) { ... }` somewhere.

Comment: i did. it displays the time weird. it shows the time like :.9888

Comment: possible duplicate of [Duration in Hours and minutes in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14067393/duration-in-hours-and-minutes-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should solve the problem for you
If needed it displays hours, minutes (with a leading zero) and seconds

```
function countdown() {
    seconds = 1000;
    delay = delay - seconds
    secs = Math.ceil(delay / seconds);
    var hrs = Math.floor(secs / 3600);
    var mins = Math.floor((secs - (hrs * 3600)) / 60);
    secs -= ((hrs * 3600) + (mins * 60));

    document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = ((hrs>0) ? hrs + ':' : '') + ((mins>0) ? ((mins>9) ? mins : '0'+mins) + ':' : '') + ((secs>9) ? secs : '0'+secs) + " until alarm goes off";
    t3 = setTimeout("countdown()", 1000);
    if (delay == 0) {
        alert('Wake UP!!!');
        DontDoIt();
    }
}
```