# How do I calculate the time difference between strings in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

is that I have two hours in string format and I need to calculate the difference in javascript, an example:

a = "10:22:57"

b = "10:30:00"

difference = 00:07:03 ?

Comment: create two diff date objects, subtract the smaller from the larger(or use Math.abs() to ensure you get a positive number), convert ms to hours:min:seconds

Comment: A little bit of search wouldn't hurt...[This for knowing how convert String into Date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619202/converting-string-to-date-in-js) and [this for subtracting two dates/time one from another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787939/check-time-difference-in-javascript)

Comment: Handling dates and times in Javascript is enough to drive strong men to drink. It's one of those times when "use a library" might well be the right response if you have anything even vaguely complex that you need to do.

Comment: consider a library indeed, something like this might do the trick https://github.com/timrwood/moment

Comment: @Koki w3schools is a terrible resource. Use MDN

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Although using `Date` or a library is perfectly fine (and probably easier), here is an example of how to do this "manually" with a little bit of math. The idea is the following:

1. Parse the string, extract hour, minutes and seconds.
2. Compute the total number of seconds.
3. Subtract both numbers.
4. Format the seconds as `hh:mm:ss`.

---

Example:

```
function toSeconds(time_str) {
    // Extract hours, minutes and seconds
    var parts = time_str.split(':');
    // compute  and return total seconds
    return parts[0] * 3600 + // an hour has 3600 seconds
           parts[1] * 60 +   // a minute has 60 seconds
           +parts[2];        // seconds
}

var difference = Math.abs(toSeconds(a) - toSeconds(b));

// compute hours, minutes and seconds
var result = [
    // an hour has 3600 seconds so we have to compute how often 3600 fits
    // into the total number of seconds
    Math.floor(difference / 3600), // HOURS
    // similar for minutes, but we have to "remove" the hours first;
    // this is easy with the modulus operator
    Math.floor((difference % 3600) / 60), // MINUTES
    // the remainder is the number of seconds
    difference % 60 // SECONDS
];

// formatting (0 padding and concatenation)
result = result.map(function(v) {
    return v < 10 ? '0' + v : v;
}).join(':');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/VDnND/)

Comment: How long did it take you to think of a solution like this! Seems like a lot of work :)

Comment: I don't remember anymore. I also don't know why I didn't use Date. Maybe I just wanted to proof that it's possible without it :)

Comment: I used this code using `Date`'s I created and it works fine! :)

Comment: What a beautiful piece of code :). Awesome

Comment: What is 'parts[1] * 60 +   +parts[2]' - + sign must be two times (?)

Comment: @phpJs: The unary `+` converts the value to a number. Compare `100 + '30'` vs `100 + +'30'` (`parts` is an array of strings).

Answer (score 4):

Make two [`Date`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) objects out of them. Then you can compare.

Get the value out of both dates you wish to compare, and make a subtraction. Like this (supposing `foo` and `bar` are dates):

```
var totalMilliseconds = foo - bar;
```

That will give you the amount of milliseconds between both. Some math will convert that to days, hours, minutes, seconds or whatever unit you wish to use. For example:

```
var seconds = totalMilliseconds / 1000;
var hours = totalMilliseconds / (1000 * 3600);
```

As for obtaining a `Date` from a `string`, you'll have to look into the constructor (check the first link), and use it in the way that suits you best. Happy coding!

Comment: actually, you can just subtract the Date objects since .valueOf() maps to .getTime() ...

Comment: @dandavis Thanks. I don't know what went through my mind when I wrote that. Corrected now.

Comment: @Koki w3schools is a terrible resource. Use MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Answer (score 3):

a really easy way if you will always have fewer than 12 hours:

```
a = "10:22:57";
b = "10:30:00";
p = "1/1/1970 ";

difference = new Date(new Date(p+b) - new Date(p+a)).toUTCString().split(" ")[4];
alert( difference ); // shows: 00:07:03
```

if you need to format for more than 12 hours, it's more complicated to render, the # of MS between the dates is correct using the this math...

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Date objects :
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

Then compare :
[How to calculate date difference in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7763327/how-to-calculate-date-difference-in-javascript)

Comment: http://www.w3fools.com/ -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date