# How to compute the difference between 2 time in jquery datetimepicker?

Tags: javascript, datetimepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I'm using jquery datetimepicker, I want to get the difference between start time and end time.

How can I calculate it using javascript/jquery code?

**I set up the start and end time in html like**.

```
<div class='input-group date' id='time_starts_at'>
  <input class="form-control" placeholder="Time Start's At *" autocomplete="off" type="text" name="" id="calendar_starts_at_time">
  <span class="input-group-addon">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
  </span>
</div>

<div class='input-group date' id='time_ends_at'>
  <input class="form-control" placeholder="Time End's At *" autocomplete="off" type="text" name="" id="calendar_ends_at_time">
  <span class="input-group-addon">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
  </span>
</div>
```

**And, my jquery codes by getting its value:**

```
var timeFrom = $start_time.data('date');
var timeTo = $end_time.data('date');
```

**Curently**, I'm doing it manually by splitting the Hour and Minutes. Adding validation on it by checking the values before subtracting it.

**Is there a best way to do it ?**

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: this may give you some idea https://jsfiddle.net/taditdash/kh0ptnu5/

Comment: Are you using jquery.timepicker?

Comment: Hi @Sami, nope. I'm using bootstrap-datetimepicker.

Comment: Hi @PandiyanCool, yes I already created the function for getting difference between 2 dates. But not in 2 time.

Comment: Have a look at http://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/

gives you call back functions as well

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

Thanks to @Felix Kling, [How do I calculate the time difference between strings in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17157337/how-do-i-calculate-the-time-difference-between-strings-in-javascript)

```
function toSeconds(time_str) {
    // Extract hours, minutes and seconds
    var parts = time_str.split(':');
    // compute  and return total seconds
    return parts[0] * 3600 + // an hour has 3600 seconds
    parts[1] * 60; // a minute has 60 seconds
}

var a = "10:55" //start time
var b = "12:00" // end time

var difference = Math.abs(toSeconds(a) - toSeconds(b));

// format time difference
var result = [
    Math.floor(difference / 3600), // an hour has 3600 seconds
    Math.floor((difference % 3600) / 60), // a minute has 60 seconds
    difference % 60
];
// 0 padding and concatation
result = result.map(function(v) {
    return v < 10 ? '0' + v : v;
}).join(':');
alert(result);
```