# Getting time difference between two times in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, time, timestamp

I have tried to get the time difference between 2 different times and i am getting it correctly for hours and minutes. But if the second is greater than the first it will getting the problem. The time is displaying with negative data.

for example

```
Start time : 00:02:59
End time   : 00:05:28
```

If i getting the difference between start and end time

```
00:05:28 - 00:02:59 = 00:3:-31
```

Which is not a correct value. I'm using the following script for getting this value.

```
var start_time = $("#startTime").val();
var end_time = $("#endTime").val();
var startHour = new Date("01/01/2007 " + start_time).getHours();
var endHour = new Date("01/01/2007 " + end_time).getHours();
var startMins = new Date("01/01/2007 " + start_time).getMinutes();
var endMins = new Date("01/01/2007 " + end_time).getMinutes();
var startSecs = new Date("01/01/2007 " + start_time).getSeconds();
var endSecs = new Date("01/01/2007 " + end_time).getSeconds();
var secDiff = endSecs - startSecs;
var minDiff = endMins - startMins;
var hrDiff = endHour - startHour;
alert(hrDiff+":"+minDiff+":"+secDiff);
```

anyone please tell me how to get the time difference between two times correctly even considering with seconds

Comment: you can convert them into seconds first or even better to miliseconds, do your arithmetic and convert them back to your format.

Comment: but if i do that it will affect minute also. i want to get a time with "HH:MM:SS" format

Comment: Check the similar post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787939/check-time-difference-in-javascript Hope this helps.

Comment: Recent ffmpeg versions have a `-to` option so you don't have to calculate the time for the `-t` parameter. See: http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#Main-options

Answer (score -7):

Try doing this

```
    var date1 = new Date(2000, 0, 1,  9, 0); // 9:00 AM
    var date2 = new Date(2000, 0, 1, 17, 0); // 5:00 PM
    if (date2 < date1) {
        date2.setDate(date2.getDate() + 1);
    }
    var diff = date2 - date1;
    // 28800000 milliseconds (8 hours)
```

You can then convert milliseconds to hour, minute and seconds like this:

```
    var msec = diff;
    var hh = Math.floor(msec / 1000 / 60 / 60);
    msec -= hh * 1000 * 60 * 60;
    var mm = Math.floor(msec / 1000 / 60);
    msec -= mm * 1000 * 60;
    var ss = Math.floor(msec / 1000);
    msec -= ss * 1000;
    // diff = 28800000 => hh = 8, mm = 0, ss = 0, msec = 0
```

Comment: Full answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1788084/529544

Comment: are downvotes because of copy&paste?