# how to calculate "time 1" - "time 2" in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, datetime, datediff

Friends,

I would like to calculate difference between two times. For example I have

```
var workedHours = '05:00:00';

var defaultWorkDay = '08:00:00';
```

So I'm needing to calc workedHours - defaultWorkDay and expect a '-03:00:00' result.

I've tried moment.js but with no success.

Do you have some suggestion?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check time difference in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787939/check-time-difference-in-javascript)

Comment: moment.js should handle this beautifully. Can you post the moment.js-based code you tried?

Comment: If you actually tried something, you should post that code and explain how you expected it to work, and what happened instead.

Comment: @DeeDee No it's not IMO.

Comment: Would you be able to convert the hours into time (like a Unix timestamp), do your arithmetic, and then convert the difference into hours?

Comment: @Pointy I've tried.

    `var worked = moment.utc("2014-11-18 05:00:00","YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");`  
    `var defaultDay = moment.utc("2014-11-18 08:00:00", "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");  `
    `var diff =  moment.utc(worked).diff(moment.utc(defaultDay));`

diff is "0"

Comment: @NabilKadimi What?! Your statement makes no sense. If you're suggesting that moment.js is in fact not a good solution, I'll point you to the first accepted answer, written by a person who never used the framework yet immediately saw how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never used moment.js , but I think this should work for you:

```js
    var defaultWorkDay = '08:00:00';
    var workedHours = '05:00:00';
    var a = moment.duration(defaultWorkDay);
    var b = moment.duration(workedHours);
    
    console.log( [ b.subtract(a).hours(), b.subtract(a).minutes(), b.subtract(a).seconds() ]
    ) // [-3:0:0]
```

```html
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/subtract/

Comment: I believe that adding 31 KB (minified) for such a basic operation is unnecessary.

Comment: I modified to work with minutes and seconds as well.

Comment: to work properly:  
`var diff = b.subtract(a);`  
`var hour = diff.hours();`  
`var minute = diff.minutes();`  
`var second = diff.seconds();`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this like [this](http://jsconsole.com/?var%20start%20%3D%20%2205%3A00%3A00%22%3B%0Avar%20end%20%3D%20%2208%3A00%3A00%22%3B%0A%0Avar%20startArr%20%3D%20start.split%28%27%3A%27%29%3B%0Avar%20endArr%20%3D%20end.split%28%27%3A%27%29%3B%20%0A%0Avar%20diffInSeconds%20%3D%20%28%20endArr[0]%20-%20startArr[0]%20%29%20*%203600%20%2B%20%28%20endArr[1]%20-%20startArr[1]%20%29%20*%2060%20%2B%20%28%20endArr[2]%20-%20startArr[2]%20%29%20%3B%0A%0Aconsole.log%20%28%20%27The%20difference%20is%20%3A%20%27%20%2B%20diffInSeconds%20%2B%20%27%20seconds.%27%29%3B) if you are sure the format is always `hours:minutes:secnodes`...:

```
var start = "05:00:00";
var end = "08:00:00";

var startArr = start.split(':');
var endArr = end.split(':'); 

var diffInSeconds = 0
    + ( endArr[0] - startArr[0] ) * 3600
    + ( endArr[1] - startArr[1] ) * 60
    + ( endArr[2] - startArr[2] ) ;

console.log ( 'The difference is : ' + diffInSeconds + ' seconds.');

// => The difference is 10800 seconds.
```

Answer (score 0):

Turn your hours into dates with time by prefixing them with a date (like below) and then do math using .getTime() on the Date object. Then convert those milliseconds into your hours, or whatever other time unit you desire.

```
  var date1 = new Date("2000-01-01 05:00:00");
  var date2 = new Date("2000-01-01 08:00:00");
  var msTimeOffset = date1.getTime() - date2.getTime();
  var hourTimeOffset = msTimeOffset / 1000 / 60 / 60;
  expect(hourTimeOffset).toBe(-3); // passes
```