# how to find difference of two times in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

could you please tell me how to how to find difference of two times in javascript ? I tried to find  but I am getting error in my fiddle here is my code

https://jsfiddle.net/fwz7mtyL/

```
var todaydate = new Date(); 
var datetime =  todaydate.getMonth()+1  + "-" 
                +todaydate.getDate() + "-"
                + todaydate.getFullYear() + " "  
                + todaydate.getHours() + ":"  
                + todaydate.getMinutes() + ":" 
                + todaydate.getSeconds();
var date2='8-6-2015 15:34:60";
var d1 = new Date(datetime);
var d2=new Date(date2);
alert(("Your Operation took  " + (d2.getTime() - d1.getTime()) + " milliseconds"))
alert(datetime)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get difference between 2 dates in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224834/get-difference-between-2-dates-in-javascript)

Comment: ok I will try and update you

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787939/check-time-difference-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Instead of create your d2 this way.

```
var date2='2015-06-08T15:34:60';
var d2=new Date('2015','06'-1,'08','15','34','60');
```

You can directly pass these parameters at the constructor like this.

```
var d2=new Date('2015','06'-1,'08','15','34','60');
```

Look it works for me. [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/fwz7mtyL/2/)