# Time difference in javascript time1-time2

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, time

I have 2 variables in javascript where 2 times has been stored for a reason.

say for ex:

```
 var currentdate = new Date(); 
    var time1 = "24:00:00"; // everytime this will be 24
    var time2 = var time2 = currentdate.getHours() +":"+ currentdate.getMinutes() ; //  this is the system time
```

need difference between the 2 times.

If have tried with `time1-time2` but it is not working.

I want to make if difference between the 2 times is x, then perform some task. I need the difference thats it.

Comment: You're trying to subtract two string, which will lead to a NaN( Not a Number)

Comment: I don’t understand what you’re asking. First, complete your code example, don’t cut it off in the middle of a string. Then, specify what you mean by difference. Difference in seconds? As a number? As a string? Difference as a specific time format? What format? Or a `Date` object? A different kind of object? Why did you think `time1 - time2` would work? They’re strings. You can’t just subtract them. If you’re looking for an algorithm to calculate the difference, show your research effort and your own attempts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check time difference in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787939/check-time-difference-in-javascript)

Comment: it is not duplicate, date is added there, but here only time will be there

Comment: yes zubair, can u please tell me how can i covert that to time... that is how the time is in the requirement...

Comment: updated my question please check it

Comment: why dont you guys read the question properly before giving a statement that it is duplicate question.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should  work if your times are in the [standard](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) format that counts the date/time as the number of milliseconds from Jan 1, 1970. See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp) for details.

```
difference = parseInt(time2) - parseInt(time1)
```

Lastly, you can set a date to tonight's midnight (the one that has already passed) like this:

```
var midnight = new Date();
midnight.setHours(0,0,0,0);
```

Then, use it to subtract your time of interest using the method above where both variables have Date type.

Comment: As I said, the numbers need to be  in the standard form. NaN means  "Not a Number." JS does not understand how to treat your entries as numbers.

Comment: also, you should be doing `var time2 = new Date();`

Comment: but in my case there will no date, only time will be there... is it possible to get difference with only times with out including date?

Comment: Yes, time is also just a number. If you are getting NaN, you need to check your time1 and time2 variables. One  of  them is not a number. Do a `typeof(time1)` and `typeof(time2)` to your console.