# Difference in time in two cells using javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to calculate the difference in time in two cells using javascript 
cell one is called DateTimeField1 and cell two is called DateTimeField2 - the time fields could go over nights ie start time 17:00 and finish time 07:00.
I am using Livecycle ES2
Can someone help please?

Comment: Do you have any code already?

Comment: yes lot of people can help. But i dont think they will until you Post your code dude what you have tried.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787939/check-time-difference-in-javascript

Comment: You can calculate the difference in their timestamps using `getTime()` i.e `DateTimeField2.getTime() - DateTimeField1.getTime()`. Then from the difference, you can find time diff. in your unit.