# How can I calculate hours before given time

Tags: javascript

My Question is how do I calculate how much hours and minutes will pass to reach specific time. I mean if we have time:
15:32, and I want to calculate how much hours is needed to 05:32 (at night), in this case should be 14 hours and 32mins.

As I don't really have that much of a knowledge and experience I haven't tried anything because I don't really know where to start.

```js
const curDate = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
console.log(curDate);

//I only know how to get the current date to string. But what next?
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate difference between 2 timestamps using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16767301/calculate-difference-between-2-timestamps-using-javascript)

Comment: If you have two `Date` values in JS, you can subtract one from another which will yield the number of milliseconds between them. You can then convert that to whatever time based metric you want.

Comment: Think of each time as a new date. There are tons of date related tutorials all over the web

Comment: Well i dont need to calculate the difference between 2 dates. I just need to know  how much hours and minutes is left to x time.

Comment: How many hours and minutes are between two times *is* the difference between two dates.

Comment: May not sound intuitive but a new date includes hours, minutes and seconds

Comment: @charlietfl I think OP is trying to find the hours and minutes until a certain time of the day is reached. i.e. How many hours until the time is 05:32 again (similar to an alarm). So i think you have wrongfully flagged the question as a duplicate

Comment: @nickzoum using Date is a simple way to do that. you even used it in your answer. Stackoverflow isn't a free code writing service, or a *"how to"* tutorial service and the duplicate was meant as a way to get started. This question could also have been closed for "too broad"

Comment: @charlietfl That is irrelevant, I am just saying that this question is not a duplicate of `Get difference between 2 dates`

Comment: @nickzoum then find a better duplicate and edit the duplicate links.  I assure you many of them exist and this question is off topic for several reasons

Comment: @charlietfl Couldn't find one, Closest i got was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42737992/making-an-alarm-clock-with-date-time). To be honest I would also expect a question such as this would had been asked already, but I can't find it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the hours and minutes until a certain time of the day is reached then you should do the following steps:

1. Create a date object with the current date
2. Create a date object with the hour and minutes you are searching for
3. Get the difference between the hours of the two (if it's smaller than 0 then that means that time has passed for the day so look for the next day)
4. Get the difference between the minutes of the two (if it's smaller than 0 then that minutes that the minutes have passed, so check for the next hour)

Since you are subtracting a date from another date you don't need to do any conversions (Local => UTC)

```js
const curDate = new Date(); // Step 1
const night = new Date(0, 0, 0, 5, 32); // Step 2
var hours = night.getHours() - curDate.getHours(); // Step 3a
if (hours < 0) hours += 24; // Step 3b
var minutes = night.getMinutes() - curDate.getMinutes(); // Step 4a
if (minutes < 0) { // Step 4b
  hours -= 1;
  minutes += 60;
}
console.log(["Hours: ", hours, ", Minutes: ", minutes].join(""));
```

Here is an example to help you understand step 4:

- 08:54 - 07:56
- 08 - 07 hours, 54 - 56 minutes
- 1 hour, -2 minutes
- 1 hour -1 hour => -2 minutes + 60 minutes
- 0 hours, 58 minutes