# Using the users inputed date when finding the difference between times

Tags: javascript

I have searched and seen how to find the difference between times but how do I use the date inputed by the user when I'm doing it? Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

```
const activity = $('#activity').val();
const startValue = $('#start-time').val();
const endValue = $('#end-time').val();
const date = $('#date').val();
const timeStart = new Date("date" + startValue).getHours();
const timeEnd = new Date("date" + endValue).getHours();
const inBetween = timeEnd - timeStart;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the number of days between two dates in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542938/how-do-i-get-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this...

```
var startDate = new Date(startValue); // start time
var endDate = new Date(endValue); //end tme

var diff = endDate - startDate;
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787939/check-time-difference-in-javascript) you can find more detailed answer.