# Typescript : find date difference in dates/hours/minutes

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, date

I am working on a date comparison and I am trying to calculate and display the difference **between two dates** in a format of dates, hours, minutes...
Date values are stored in the DB like:

```
EndDate : 2018-11-29 10:49:49.9396033
PurchaseDate: 2018-11-29 10:49:07.4154497
```

And in my Angular component, I have:

```
let result = new Date(res.endDate).valueOf() - new Date(res.purchaseDate).valueOf();
```

This leads to: `42524` which I am not sure what it represents.

I wonder what is the proper way to calculate the time difference between two dates and also how can I display the result in a proper and readable way.

Any help is welcome

Comment: My recommended way of handling date comparison would be through the use of a very respectable library called momentjs. Excellent and reliable tool for handling dates, doing comparisons and manipulation. I think it will save you a lot of time and hassle.

Comment: You might want to checkout - http://momentjs.com/.

Comment: @George George, by the way, that difference you've listed is the difference in milliseconds between the two date values you've got.

Comment: Some nice ways to do it with plain JS as well here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787939/check-time-difference-in-javascript

Comment: 42524  is (49.939-07.415)sec*1000 so basically the difference in date is being displayed in milliseconds

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check time difference in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787939/check-time-difference-in-javascript)

Answer (score 8):

[Working Example in codepen](https://codepen.io/AnasRezk/pen/mQoXmQ?editors=1010)

```
 let endDate = new Date("2018-11-29 10:49:07.4154497");
 let purchaseDate = new Date("2018-11-29 10:49:49.9396033");
 let diffMs = (purchaseDate - endDate); // milliseconds
 let diffDays = Math.floor(diffMs / 86400000); // days
 let diffHrs = Math.floor((diffMs % 86400000) / 3600000); // hours
 let diffMins = Math.round(((diffMs % 86400000) % 3600000) / 60000); // minutes
 console.log(diffDays + " days, " + diffHrs + " hours, " + diffMins + " 
 minutes");
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `getTime()` method to get the difference time in milliseconds

```
let time = purchaseDate.getTime() - endDate.getTime();
```

You can then format the date as you want with the **DatePipe** librairy : https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

Comment: thank you for the reply. I did this approach but then I face "getTime() is not a function"..

Comment: You can try to look at this article: https://expertcodeblog.wordpress.com/2017/12/12/typescript-error-gethours-is-not-a-function/

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are pure javascript way of doing it like in [Check time difference in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787939/check-time-difference-in-javascript)

or you can reuse the efforts put in by engineers who delevloped moment.js. In moment.js, there is a concept called duration whose link is - https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/ 
and you can even find the difference in duration by referencing docs here - https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/diffing/