# Time/date how to make in one number and do math stuff to it and untill the day ends

Tags: javascript, php, html, date, time

Hello guys so into web page im gettting date/time variable which looks like `2018-12-05 07:19:54` and I am getting IN or EXIT. Here is cauculating if person is coming in or going out and how long he has been in and I need seperate every entrence from `2018-12-05 00:01` to `2018-12-05 23:59:59`.

Btw the file looks like this

[image]

Does anyone know how to do math? Example `(2018-12-05  07:19:54)-(2018-12-05  07:50:05) = 31min` in the end it would be  at work he was 31min and cauculate that untill the day ends. Anyone knows any ideas how to cauculate that sort of kind stuff?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check time difference in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787939/check-time-difference-in-javascript)

Comment: if you could add your code here. What have you tried so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can using date_diff function in PHP

For example:

```
$date1=date_create("2018-12-05  07:19:54");
$date2=date_create("2018-12-05  07:50:05");
$diff=date_diff($date1,$date2);
echo $diff->format("'%i Minute %s Seconds'");
```

For running code check [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/262e54c89a80a982436fc12d923d9e7da56bb248)

Check [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php) for complete format response

Comment: is there any way out print the date witch is in there and cauculate until the date is changed?

Comment: I posted what i have wrriten

Answer (score 0):

PHP's [Date Time](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class has method called [diff](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php). This method would return a [DateInterval](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) object, you can easily retrieve values of year, month, day... from that object.

Answer (score 0):

Soo this is what i have done and it cauculates the time from in to exit

```js
<?php
error_reporting(0); //disable all errors and notices
require_once "Classes/PHPExcel.php";
  $chosenPerson = $_GET["dla_darbuotojo_pasirinkimas"];
  $tmpfname = "visi.xls";
  $excelReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReaderForFile($tmpfname);
  $excelObj = $excelReader->load($tmpfname);
  $worksheet = $excelObj->getSheet(0);
  $lastRow = $worksheet->getHighestRow();
  $aInT = "Administracija[In]";
  $vInT = "Vartai[In]";
  $aExT = "Administracija[Exit]";
  $vExT = "Vartai[Exit]";
  
  $goingIn = false;
  $goingExt = false;

  $goingInValue = 0;
  $goingExtValue = 0;

  echo "<table>";
  for ($row = 1; $row <= $lastRow; $row++) {
   if ($chosenPerson ==  ($worksheet->getCell('D'.$row)->getValue()) ) {
    if (!$goingIn or !$goingExt) {
     //checking if the person alredy went in
     if ((($worksheet->getCell('G'.$row)->getValue()) == $aInT) or (($worksheet->getCell('G'.$row)->getValue()) == $vInT)) {
      //if the person went in
      $goingIn = true;
      echo "<tr><td>";
      $goingInValue = $worksheet->getCell('F'.$row)->getValue();
      echo "</td><td>";
      echo $worksheet->getCell('D'.$row)->getValue();
      echo "</td><td>";
      echo $worksheet->getCell('F'.$row)->getValue();
      echo "</td><td>";
      echo $worksheet->getCell('G'.$row)->getValue();
      echo "</td><td>";
      echo "</td><td>";
      echo "</td><td>";
      
      for ($erow= $row +1; ; $erow++){
       if ($chosenPerson ==  ($worksheet->getCell('D'.$erow)->getValue()) ) {
        if ((($worksheet->getCell('G'.$erow)->getValue()) == $aExT) or (($worksheet->getCell('G'.$erow)->getValue()) == $vExT)) {
         $goingExtValue = $worksheet->getCell('F'.$erow)->getValue();
         $goingExt=true;
         
         echo $worksheet->getCell('D'.$erow)->getValue();
         echo "</td><td>";
         echo $worksheet->getCell('F'.$erow)->getValue();
         echo "</td><td>";
         echo $worksheet->getCell('G'.$erow)->getValue();
         echo "</td><td>";
         
         $date1=date_create($goingInValue);
         $date2=date_create($goingExtValue);
         $diff=date_diff($date2,$date1);
         echo $diff->format("'%h Valandos %i Minutes %s Sekundes'");
         echo "</td><tr>";
         $goingIn = false;
         $goingExt = false;
         break;
         $row=$erow;
        }
       }       
      }
     } 
    }
    
    
    //echo "<tr><td>";
    //echo $worksheet->getCell('D'.$row)->getValue();
    //echo "</td><td>";
    //echo $worksheet->getCell('F'.$row)->getValue();
    //echo "</td><td>";
    //echo $worksheet->getCell('G'.$row)->getValue();
    //echo "</td><tr>";
   }
  }
  echo "</table>";
  

?>
```