# Calculate time remaining between now and a precise hour of next day

Tags: javascript, date, time

What's the most concise, performant way to get in *Javascript* the minutes remaining between now, and the upcoming day at `01:00` (am)?

Then, once the current time is after `01:00`, I start calculating the difference to the next.

Comment: You have to be precise in your question. What do you mean 'or perhaps already current'? Also, have you tried anything yet? You can get the current time with `var now = new Date()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check time difference in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787939/check-time-difference-in-javascript)

Comment: @TKoL if current time is `00:30`, I would need to calculate the difference on the same day. If current time is after `1:00`, start calculating the difference to the next.

Comment: I'll describe to you the logic, and you can figure out how to implement it then. What i would do is make two Date variables, one for now and one for 'one o'clock'. On the one for one o'clock, use 'setHours' `oneOclock.setHours(1,0,0,0)` to set it to 1 AM. Then, check if that date is in the past relative to now, if it is in the past add one day to it. Then you can just subtract the dates from each other to get the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let now = new Date();
let next1am = new Date();
next1am.setHours(1, 0, 0, 0); // same as now, but at 01:00:00.000
if (next1am < now) next1am.setDate(next1am.getDate() + 1); // bump date if past
let millisecondDiff = next1am - now;
let minuteDiff = Math.floor(millisecondDiff / 1000 / 60);
```

Answer (score 3):

in javascript, a specified date can be provided like this

```
var date1 = new Date('June 6, 2019 03:24:00');
```

or it can be specified like this

```
var date2 = new Date('2019-6-6T03:24:00');
```

javascript can natively subtract 2 dates

```
console.log(date1 - date2);
//expected 0;
```

using this method will output the difference in the dates in milliseconds,
to get minutes you'll want to divide the value by 60000;

so

```
var futureTime = new Date('2019-06-06T07:24:00');
//there must be a 0 infront of 1 digit numbers or it is an invalid date
var now = new Date();
var difference = (futureTime - now) / 60000;
//get minutes by dividing by 60000
//doing Date() with no arguments returns the current date
```

read about the javascript Date object here for more information
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: Parsing of `new Date('June 6, 2019 03:24:00')` is implementation dependent, so while you *can* do that, it's not a good idea. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

you can you `moment.js` here

```
var current = new Date()
var end = new Date(start.getTime() + 3600*60)// end time to calculate diff

var minDiff = end - start; // in millisec
```

Comment: Is there a solution that doesn't use external libraries?

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate by pure JavaScript:

```
let today = new Date();
let [y,M,d,h,m,s] = '2019-06-04 05:00:11'.split(/[- :]/);
let yourDate = new Date(y,parseInt(M)-1,d,h,parseInt(m)+30,s);
let diffMs = (yourDate - today);
let diffDays = Math.floor(diffMs / 86400000); // days
let diffHrs = Math.floor((diffMs % 86400000) / 3600000); // hours
let diffMins = (diffDays * 24 * 60) 
               +  (diffHrs *60) 
               +  Math.round(((diffMs % 86400000) % 3600000) / 60000); // The overall result
                                                                       // in minutes
```

In, addition avoid using the built–in parser for any non–standard format, e.g. in Safari new Date("2019-04-22 05:00:11") returns an invalid date. You really shouldn't even use if for standardized formats as you will still get unexpected results for some formats. [Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)