# Javascript: How do I use date values in the expression of a for loop?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I wrote this for loop:

```
// I expect to get the day of 10/12/2019
const startDate = parseInt(new Date('10/12/2019').getDate());

// I expect to get the day of 22/12/2019
const endDate = parseInt(new Date('22/12/2019').getDate());

// Creating an empty array to push data later on
let freedays = [];

// for loop where i equals the day of the startdate: '10', and where the condition is that 
let i has to be smaller of equal to endDate: '22' for the loop to stop.
for (let i = startDate; i <= endDate; i++) {
        freedays.push(i)
      }

console.log(freedays)
```

I always get an empty array when executing this function, whereas I want to get the days in between startDate and EndDate.

Could anyone help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: These are non-standard date formats, so your environment is likely producing an invalid date for `'22/12/2019'`

Comment: startDate and endDate are NaN, the 'i' in your for loop must be a number.

Comment: Start with simple debugging and `console.log` all involved variables…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong date format. It is expecting `mm/dd/yyyy` but you are giving it `dd/mm/yyyy`. The 22 for the month gives error and makes `endDate NaN`

```js
const startDate = parseInt(new Date('12/10/2019').getDate());
const endDate = parseInt(new Date('12/22/2019').getDate());
let freedays = [];
for (let i = startDate; i <= endDate; i++) {
        freedays.push(i)
      }
console.log(freedays)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, welcome to StackOverflow!

Secondly ... There's a bit of misunderstanding in your code, and you really need to re-think what you are doing, as it works fine if 2 dates have the same month and year :)

first of all, try debug things:

- open console in any browser (F12 on windows) and write `new Date('22/12/2019').getDate()` and see what happens
- you will find out that it returns `NaN` (Not a Number)
- why parsing an already `number` into a `number`?
- a bigger idea, is to write code in a UI so you can debug it line by line ... learning this will start improving your code and the way you find your own mistakes

Now, talking about code ...

**If this is for learning proposes: great**, if not, no need to re-invent the wheel, momentJs and DateFns already have such functions

using [momentJs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/)

```
var moment = require('moment');
var d = moment("12-22-2019").diff(moment("12-10-2019"), "days");
// 12
```

using [DateFns](https://date-fns.org/v2.8.1/docs/differenceInDays)

```
var differenceInDays = require('date-fns/differenceInDays');
var d = differenceInDays(new Date("12-22-2019"), new Date("12-10-2019"));
// 12
```

if is only for testing proposes:

- you would be better off by using the `Date` object itself and not a part of it, so you no longer bound to the same month and year
- remember to, soon you have the difference between 2 dates, convert it to the unit you want (seconds, days, etc)

all this is better answered in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1788084/28004)