# how to calculate time difference between hours in javascript?

Tags: javascript

i.e. I want to calculate the time difference from 8.30pm to 9pm in 24hr format.
so far i have:

```
let start = 2030;
let end = 2100;
let timeDiff = end - start;
```

But this gives me 70 as an answer.
How do I get 30 minutes as an answer?

Comment: This is elementary school level math ...

Comment: yes but i dont know how to code it in js

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check time difference in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787939/check-time-difference-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the correct format of your time. you can calculate like below.

```
let start = new Date('1900/01/01 08:30 PM');
let end = new Date('1900/01/01 09:00 PM');
let minDiff = (Math.abs(start - end) / 1000)/60;
let hourDiff = ((Math.abs(start - end) / 1000)/60)/60;
let dayDiff = parseInt((((Math.abs(start - end) / 1000)/60)/60)/24);
```