# calculation between two time slots javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

calculation between two time slots, I retrieve a time from my database example: 11:50 and the current time is 18:50. How to calculate interval between the two schedules? thank you for help.

```
const currentTime = new Date();
    const timeMinutes = currentTime.getMinutes()
    
    if(timeMinutes < 10){
        var timeMinute = '0' + timeMinutes
    }else{
        timeMinute = timeMinutes
    }
const heureCommande = currentTime.getHours() + ":" + timeMinute
    console.log(heureCommande)
console.log(heureCommande - 18:50)
```

Comment: What is your expectation for `console.log(heureCommande - 18:50)`?

Comment: What does _"calculate interval"_ mean? An interval has a start and an end, e.g. `['11:50', '18:50']` could be considered an interval. What's the expected result?

Comment: @hoangdv I would like to know the hour and minute difference between the two times

Comment: @jabaa I would like to know the length of time between the two schedules

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check time difference in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787939/check-time-difference-in-javascript#1788084)

Comment: convert time into seconds.