# How to know date is today?

Tags: javascript

I am trying this but is not working... why?

```
<html>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var today=new Date(); //today is Nov 28, 2010
        today.setHours(0);
        today.setMinutes(0);
        today.setSeconds(0);
        document.write(today+" ");

        var today2 = new Date("November 28, 2010");
        document.write(today2 + " ");
        if (today == today2) { document.write("==");
        if (!(today > today2) && !(today < today2) ) {document.write("==  ");}
        if (today > today2) { document.write(">  ");}
        if (today >= today2 ){ document.write(">=  ");}
        if (today < today2 ) { document.write("<  ");}
        if (today <= today2 ){ document.write("<=  ");}

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And I always get this:

```
Sun Nov 28 2010 00:00:00 GMT+0900 (JST) Sun Nov 28 2010 00:00:00 GMT+0900 (JST) > >=
```

Aren't both dates to be the same? Hence, I should get `==` printed but is not happening... ;(

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Did you ask for a way to compute the date difference or a way to determine if a given date is today? For the first question, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41948/how-do-i-get-the-difference-between-two-dates-in-javascript. For the second, check my answer.

Comment: Thank you all for the answers... this was kind of a js experiment ;)

Answer (score 71, accepted):

They will never match because you're comparing two separate `Date` object instances.

You need to get some common value that can be compared. For example `.toDateString()`.

```
today.toDateString() == today2.toDateString();  // true
```

If you just compare two separate `Date` objects, even if they have the exact same date value, they are still different.

For example:

```
today == new Date( today );  // false
```

They are the same date/time value, but are not the same object, so the result is `false`.

Comment: Is there a mechanic for overriding OP selection?

Answer (score 22):

```
function today(td) {
    var d = new Date();
    return td.getDate() == d.getDate() && td.getMonth() == d.getMonth() && td.getFullYear() == d.getFullYear();
}
```

Comment: This solution is faster than today.toDateString() == today2.toDateString(); Performance test result at jsbench.me shows that comparing strings is 99% slower. At http://jsben.ch/ it is 80% slower.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by setting time to `00:00:00` for the given date and for today's date, and then compare them.

The code example is below:

```
function checkDateIsToday (today, givenDate) {
  
  if(today.setHours(0,0,0,0) === givenDate.setHours(0,0,0,0)) {
     console.log('Date is todays date');
  } else {
     console.log('Date is not todays date');
  } 

}

checkDateIsToday(new Date(), new Date('2020-07-10'));
```