# Date comparison in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have some date in milliseconds as `1425133515000` . Now in javascript I need to verify whether `1425133515000`  is `today` or not. Is it possible?

I need one method which takes date in milli seconds and return true if date in milliseconds is today.

Comment: You should try a bit by yourself and look around before asking questions.

Comment: I am new to Javascript. Could u plz help me?

Comment: If you are in need of date manipulation there is a very good library for doing exactly that: http://momentjs.com/

Comment: It looks like you're using a Unix Timestamp which is actually in seconds, and not in milliseconds. Check out the `Moment.js` project for this kind of operation. Here's a documentation link: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/unix-timestamp/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

New date object from miliseconds:

```
var dateFromMs = new Date(1425133515000);
```

And comparsion based on [How to know date is today?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4292990/how-to-know-date-is-today):

```
var today = new Date();
if (today.toDateString() === dateFromMs.toDateString()) {
    alert('today');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`Date constructor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Parameters) taking an Integer value representing the number of milliseconds since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC (Unix Epoch) - which is what your integer value represents:

```
vat date = new Date(1425133515000);
var now = new Date();
```

Now all that's left is compare is whether the 2 dates represent the same calendar day:

```
var isSameDay = 
    date.getDate() === now.getDate() && 
    date.getMonth() === now.getMonth() &&
    date.getFullYear() === now.getFullYear();
```