# How to Count an UpdatePanel Progress?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

I need to count the rendering time of an UpdatePanel inside my page.
Someone knows how to do that?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could subscribe for the [beginRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397432.aspx) and [endRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383810.aspx) callbacks and calculate the elapsed time between them.

```
function pageLoad() {
    var manager = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    if (manager != null) {
        manager.add_beginRequest(Request_Begin);
        manager.add_endRequest(Request_End);
    }
}

function Request_Begin(sender, args)
{
    // TODO: start your timer here (new Date())
}

function Request_End(sender, args) {
    // TODO: get the current date and measure the difference
    // with theone obtained in the beginRequest
}
```

The [following thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41948/how-do-i-get-the-difference-between-two-dates-in-javascript) will help you in implementing the TODOs I left in my code.

Comment: Yeah thanks, but I'm still facing troubles with that one.
The problem is the JS Date Calculate, as you said, I opened the another thread and tried to use the milliseconds format to calculate it, but without success.

Comment: If is possible, could you please help me on this fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/felipekm/gaZVH/

Comment: @FelipeKM, did you read the following thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41948/how-do-i-get-the-difference-between-two-dates-in-javascript?

Comment: Yes I did, could you please read my fiddle?
http://jsfiddle.net/felipekm/gaZVH/6/

Comment: @FelipeKM, yes, I opened your fiddle. There are errors with it. For example `alert(_dateDiff.);` is not valid javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I'd like to thanks @Darin for all support, it was great!
With the @darin suggestion I could make my target with some Math included such below:

```
    function get_time_difference(earlierDate, laterDate) {
    var nTotalDiff = laterDate.getTime() - earlierDate.getTime();
    var oDiff = new Object();

    oDiff.minutes = Math.floor(nTotalDiff / 1000 / 60);
    nTotalDiff -= oDiff.minutes * 1000 * 60;

    oDiff.seconds = Math.floor(nTotalDiff / 1000);
    oDiff.milliseconds = Math.floor(nTotalDiff * 1000);

    return oDiff;
}

var timeInit;
var timeFinal;

function pageLoad() {
    var manager = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    if (manager != null) {
        manager.add_beginRequest(Request_Begin);
        manager.add_endRequest(Request_End);
    }
}

function Request_Begin(sender, args) {
    timeInit = new Date();  
}

function Request_End(sender, args) {        
    timeFinal = new Date();
    var diff = get_time_difference(timeInit, timeFinal);
    alert('Minutes: ' + diff.minutes + '\nSeconds: ' + diff.seconds + '.' + diff.milliseconds);        
}
```

Hope this be useful for others devs.
Thanks!