# how to calculate date difference in java script?

Tags: javascript, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get the difference between two Dates in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41948/how-do-i-get-the-difference-between-two-dates-in-javascript)

I have a html form which contains 3 fields:

1. from_date
2. to_date
3. no_ofdays

I want to calculate the difference between `from_date` and `to_date` and the difference will be shown in `no_ofdays` field.
My requirement is the `to_date` must not be less than `from_date`. And if the condition fails
it should not calculate the difference and also the `to_date` should remain `null`.

I want to do it using JavaScript.

Comment: @user1369099 please update the question with the code. Anyway, I think the duplicate questions posted might have answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

Briefly, this is how you do it:

1. Parse the values of the fields into [`Date` objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date). [Datejs](http://www.datejs.com/) can help you do this.
2. `Date` objects support the `<` and `-` operators, letting you do what you want.
3. When you subtract two `Date` objects, the result is the difference in milliseconds.
4. If you divide the difference in milliseconds by the number of milliseconds in a day, then you get how many days there are between the dates.
5. You can then put the result in the result field.