# How do I subtract time in javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies, time

I currently am setting a cookie in my code that last for 10 minutes. On the page I want to tell the person how many minutes are left before the cookie expires. So what I do is set Another code to keep the time when the cookie was set.

But I don't know how to subtract the 2 time (the cookie time - current time).

For example, if I set the cookie at 12:55. How would I get the different between the time, lets say: 1:03 to get "2 minutes left"?

Really have no clue how to do this, but I hope you do.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get the difference between two Dates in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41948/how-do-i-get-the-difference-between-two-dates-in-javascript)

Comment: @sczizzo I didn't try anything. I dont know what to try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just subtract dates in JavaScript.

```
var millisecondsBetween = (new Date(2012, 1, 1)) - (new Date(2011, 1, 1));
```

will yield the number of milliseconds between them because the `-` operator coerces its arguments to numbers which ends up calling `Date.prototype.valueOf` which just returns the number of milliseconds since the start of the epoch.

Comment: You can put time inside the Date also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: @Shawn31313 this is exactly what you need.

Comment: and I need to display it in minutes. I dont get how this is anything what i need.

Comment: @Shawn31313 - Did you learn Math in your school? 1 second has 1000 milliseconds, so 1 minute 60000 milliseconds. If you get `120000` from subtracting two dates (times), then that means `2 minutes`.

Comment: Yes I understand that. I have a cookie with a time like this: "8:42" and then I need to subtract the current time to get the difference. So no. This isn't what im looking for.

Comment: @Shawn31313 `(new Date() - new Date( 2012,5,16, 8, 42, 0 , 0 ,0 )) / 60000` gives me `25` when I ran that code 9:07.

Comment: You asked how to subtract time values, not how pull time values out of a string.

Comment: From `12:01`, to pull out hour: `/^(\d+):/`, minute: `/(\d+)$/`. `txt.match(/^(\d+):/)[1]` is `12`.

Comment: Thanks @Esailija for the example. Never really took time to learn much about the Date object so I forgot that you can get the time with that also. Thank you.