# JavaScript Calc Year and Month between 2 Dates

Tags: javascript, date

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get the difference between two Dates in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41948/how-do-i-get-the-difference-between-two-dates-in-javascript)

I wanted to know how javascript can count the years and months between two dates. So for example between 26/10/2012 and 26/11/2013, there are 1 year and 1 month

I have tried it so but it is wrong :(

```
var diff =  (new Date(y, m - 1, d).getTime(2011,(11-1),26) - new Date(2012, (11-1), 26).getTime()) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24 / 30;
```

Comment: @Sibu: The problem is noone is answering his questions

Answer (score 3):

Assuming two dates, `d1` and `d2`, where `d2` is the greater of the two:

```
var month_diff = (d2.getFullYear() - d1.getFullYear()) * 12 + d2.getMonth() - d1.getMonth();
var years = floor(month_diff / 12);
var months = month_diff % 12;
alert(years + 'years and ' + months + ' months');
```

If your requirement is only to count full months you could add the following after the first line:

```
if (d2.getDate() - d1.getDate() < 0 && month_diff > 0) {
   month_diff--;
}
```

Comment: for instance, d1 = 2013.10.5, d2 = 2014.1.3, the return month should be 2, NOT 3

Comment: Updated answer with details on how to only count full months.