# Javascript return number of days,hours,minutes,seconds between two dates

Tags: javascript, datetime

Does anyone can link me to some tutorial where I can find out how to return days , hours , minutes, seconds in javascript between 2 unix datetimes?

I have:

```
var date_now = unixtimestamp;
var date_future = unixtimestamp;
```

I would like to return (live) how many days,hours,minutes,seconds left from the date_now to the date_future.

Comment: `date_future - date_now` is the seconds and from there you make your way up to minutes (60 secs) and hours (3600 secs), etc... Where exactly are you having problems?

Comment: @Lix oh great this should be the answer man, put it i'll flagcheck that

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41948/how-do-i-get-the-difference-between-two-dates-in-javascript

Comment: no end of resources in a google search for `javascript date`

Comment: same exact question asked twice today!

Answer (score 240, accepted):

Just figure out the difference in seconds (don't forget JS timestamps are actually measured in milliseconds) and decompose that value:

```
// get total seconds between the times
var delta = Math.abs(date_future - date_now) / 1000;

// calculate (and subtract) whole days
var days = Math.floor(delta / 86400);
delta -= days * 86400;

// calculate (and subtract) whole hours
var hours = Math.floor(delta / 3600) % 24;
delta -= hours * 3600;

// calculate (and subtract) whole minutes
var minutes = Math.floor(delta / 60) % 60;
delta -= minutes * 60;

// what's left is seconds
var seconds = delta % 60;  // in theory the modulus is not required
```

**EDIT** code adjusted because I just realised that the original code returned the total number of hours, etc, not the number of hours left after counting whole days.

Comment: I'd change ```var seconds = delta % 60;``` to ```var seconds = Math.floor(delta % 60);```

Comment: @BarryCarlyon I wouldn't - the OP might want to know about those rounded off milliseconds.

Comment: A valid point @alnitak but you'd probably want to split milliseconds out to it's own var in that case

Comment: can anyone please explain what is 86400, 3600, 60. Why we use it to calculate?

Comment: @BearNithi they're the number of seconds in a day, an hour, and a minute.

Comment: `Math.abs` in first-line abstracts the error if date_future is past date, I would suggest check date first, before you do `Math.abs(date_future - date_now)`

Comment: Nice! I added an updated version of this with a runnable code snippet at https://stackoverflow.com/a/73564092/537998

Comment: inappropriate edits rolled back

Answer (score 64):

Here's in javascript: (For example, the future date is New Year's Day)

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/yentup/fKA9X/1/)** (updates every second)

```js
var dateFuture = new Date(new Date().getFullYear() +1, 0, 1);
var dateNow = new Date();

var seconds = Math.floor((dateFuture - (dateNow))/1000);
var minutes = Math.floor(seconds/60);
var hours = Math.floor(minutes/60);
var days = Math.floor(hours/24);

hours = hours-(days*24);
minutes = minutes-(days*24*60)-(hours*60);
seconds = seconds-(days*24*60*60)-(hours*60*60)-(minutes*60);
  
console.log("Time until new year:\nDays: " + days + " Hours: " + hours + " Minutes: " + minutes + " Seconds: " + seconds);
```

Comment: The only one that worked for me!

Answer (score 49):

I call it the "snowman ☃ method" and I think it's a little more flexible when you need additional timespans like *weeks, moths, years, centuries...* and don't want too much repetitive code:

```js
var date_future = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 1000);
var date_now = new Date();
 
 var d = Math.abs(date_future - date_now) / 1000;                           // delta
    var r = {};                                                                // result
    var s = {                                                                  // structure
        year: 31536000,
        month: 2592000,
        week: 604800, // uncomment row to ignore
        day: 86400,   // feel free to add your own row
        hour: 3600,
        minute: 60,
        second: 1
    };

    Object.keys(s).forEach(function(key){
        r[key] = Math.floor(d / s[key]);
        d -= r[key] * s[key];
    });

    // for example: {year:0,month:0,week:1,day:2,hour:34,minute:56,second:7}
    console.log(r);
```

Have a
<kbd>**[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/RienNeVaPlus/vmhguhm3/15/)**</kbd> / <kbd>**[ES6 Version (2018)](https://jsfiddle.net/RienNeVaPlus/pzw1L47j/1/)**</kbd> / <kbd>**[TypeScript Version (2019)](https://gist.github.com/RienNeVaPlus/024de3431ae95546d60f2acce128a7e2)**</kbd>

<sup>*Inspired by [Alnitak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6782/alnitak)'s answer.*</sup>

Comment: Very elegant solution

Comment: Note that this code does depend on the keys of `s` being enumerated in the specified order, which is only guaranteed true in ES2015 or later.

Comment: Note this solution is specific for months which contain 30 days. Months with 28, 29, 31 days are not supported here.

Comment: Made my day, Thank you

Answer (score 17):

A Little bit different flavour (maybe for some ppl more readable) it works in JavaScript and as little bonus it **works in TypeScript** as well.

If you make sure the first date is always greater than the second than you don't need the Math.abs() Also the round brackets around the modulo operation are unnecessary. I kept them for clearance.

```js
let diffTime = Math.abs(new Date().valueOf() - new Date('2021-11-22T18:30:00').valueOf());
let days = diffTime / (24*60*60*1000);
let hours = (days % 1) * 24;
let minutes = (hours % 1) * 60;
let secs = (minutes % 1) * 60;
[days, hours, minutes, secs] = [Math.floor(days), Math.floor(hours), Math.floor(minutes), Math.floor(secs)]

console.log(days+'d', hours+'h', minutes+'m', secs+'s');
```

Comment: Brilliant solution. Thanks

Comment: Glad i could help! I just had the case that the second date was sometimes greater than the first. So I added the Math.abs() around the dates - that makes sure that the greatness of the dates doesn't make a difference and you can swap them around.

Comment: Yes, I swapped dates for my case

Comment: somehow if you add 29 days to current date - then the diff is `28 days, 23 hours 59 minutes 59 seconds`, but if you add 30 days, then the diff is `30 days, 0 hours 59 minutes 59 seconds`. I.e. one extra hour is added. Something is wrong with this and the other answers.. `const dataAvailableToDate = new Date()
dataAvailableToDate.setDate(dataAvailableToDate.getDate() + 30)`

Comment: Notice that in one month a lot of countries change from summer to winter time -1 hour. Its a little counter intuitive tho that it adds 1 hour if the clock is set 1 hour back but it makes sense since from today's perspective it is like you add another hour.

Comment: By the way javascript does these timezone things automatically as you can see - its a feature

Answer (score 12):

my solution is not as clear as that, but I put it as another example

```js
console.log(duration('2019-07-17T18:35:25.235Z', '2019-07-20T00:37:28.839Z'));

function duration(t0, t1){
    let d = (new Date(t1)) - (new Date(t0));
    let weekdays     = Math.floor(d/1000/60/60/24/7);
    let days         = Math.floor(d/1000/60/60/24 - weekdays*7);
    let hours        = Math.floor(d/1000/60/60    - weekdays*7*24            - days*24);
    let minutes      = Math.floor(d/1000/60       - weekdays*7*24*60         - days*24*60         - hours*60);
    let seconds      = Math.floor(d/1000          - weekdays*7*24*60*60      - days*24*60*60      - hours*60*60      - minutes*60);
    let milliseconds = Math.floor(d               - weekdays*7*24*60*60*1000 - days*24*60*60*1000 - hours*60*60*1000 - minutes*60*1000 - seconds*1000);
    let t = {};
    ['weekdays', 'days', 'hours', 'minutes', 'seconds', 'milliseconds'].forEach(q=>{ if (eval(q)>0) { t[q] = eval(q); } });
    return t;
}
```

Comment: Love it, returns results equivalent to postgres's treatment of datetime diffs.

Answer (score 11):

Please note that calculating only based on differences will not cover all cases: leap years and switching of "daylight savings time".

Javascript has poor built-in library for working with dates. I suggest you use a third party javascript library, e.g. [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com); you can see [here](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/) the function you were looking for.

Answer (score 7):

Use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) library, for example:

```
var time = date_future - date_now;
var seconds = moment.duration(time).seconds();
var minutes = moment.duration(time).minutes();
var hours   = moment.duration(time).hours();
var days    = moment.duration(time).days();
```

Answer (score 7):

Because MomentJS is quite heavy and sub-optimized, people not afraid to use a module should probably look at `date-fns` instead, which provides an [intervalToDuration](https://date-fns.org/v2.16.1/docs/intervalToDuration) method which does what you want:

```js
const result = intervalToDuration({
  start: new Date(dateNow),
  end: new Date(dateFuture),
})
```

And which would return an object looking like so:

```js
{
  years: 39,
  months: 2,
  days: 20,
  hours: 7,
  minutes: 5,
  seconds: 0,
}
```

Then you can even use [formatDuration](https://date-fns.org/v2.16.1/docs/formatDuration) to display this object as a string using the parameters you prefer

Answer (score 6):

Here is a code example. I used simple calculations instead of using precalculations like 1 day is 86400 seconds. So you can follow the logic with ease.

```js
    // Calculate time between two dates:
    var date1 = new Date('1110-01-01 11:10');
    var date2 = new Date();
    
    console.log('difference in ms', date1 - date2);
    
    // Use Math.abs() so the order of the dates can be ignored and you won't
    // end up with negative numbers when date1 is before date2.
    console.log('difference in ms abs', Math.abs(date1 - date2));
    console.log('difference in seconds', Math.abs(date1 - date2) / 1000);
    
    var diffInSeconds = Math.abs(date1 - date2) / 1000;
    var days = Math.floor(diffInSeconds / 60 / 60 / 24);
    var hours = Math.floor(diffInSeconds / 60 / 60 % 24);
    var minutes = Math.floor(diffInSeconds / 60 % 60);
    var seconds = Math.floor(diffInSeconds % 60);
    var milliseconds = Math.round((diffInSeconds - Math.floor(diffInSeconds)) * 1000);
    
    console.log('days', days);
    console.log('hours', ('0' + hours).slice(-2));
    console.log('minutes', ('0' + minutes).slice(-2));
    console.log('seconds', ('0' + seconds).slice(-2));
    console.log('milliseconds', ('00' + milliseconds).slice(-3));
```

Comment: useful after searching lot for get milliseconds part. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

**Short and flexible with support for negative values**, although by using two comma expressions :)

```
function timeUnitsBetween(startDate, endDate) {
  let delta = Math.abs(endDate - startDate) / 1000;
  const isNegative = startDate > endDate ? -1 : 1;
  return [
    ['days', 24 * 60 * 60],
    ['hours', 60 * 60],
    ['minutes', 60],
    ['seconds', 1]
  ].reduce((acc, [key, value]) => (acc[key] = Math.floor(delta / value) * isNegative, delta -= acc[key] * isNegative * value, acc), {});
}
```

**Example:**

```
timeUnitsBetween(new Date("2019-02-11T02:12:03+00:00"), new Date("2019-02-11T01:00:00+00:00"));
// { days: -0, hours: -1, minutes: -12, seconds: -3 }
```

Inspired by [RienNeVaPlu͢s](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32514236/1376947) solution.

Answer (score 4):

The best library that I know of for duration breakdown is [countdown.js](http://countdownjs.org/). It handles all the hard cases such as leap years and daylight savings as [csg mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13904025/67824), and even allows you to specify fuzzy concepts such as months and weeks. Here's the code for your case:

```
//assuming these are in *seconds* (in case of MS don't multiply by 1000 below)
var date_now = 1218374; 
var date_future = 29384744;

diff = countdown(date_now * 1000, date_future * 1000, 
            countdown.DAYS | countdown.HOURS | countdown.MINUTES | countdown.SECONDS);
alert("days: " + diff.days + " hours: " + diff.hours + 
      " minutes: " + diff.minutes + " seconds: " + diff.seconds);

//or even better
alert(diff.toString());
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8p33x9Le/3/), but it would probably only work in FireFox or in Chrome with web security disabled, since countdown.js is hosted with a *text/plain* MIME type (you're supposed to serve the file, not link to countdownjs.org).

Answer (score 4):

For those who wants only hours and minutes use this

```js
const oldDate = new Date("2021-04-28T13:17:31.000Z")
const newDate = new Date("2021-04-28T22:08:07.000Z")
const msToTime = (ms) => ({
    hours: Math.trunc(ms/3600000),
    minutes: Math.trunc((ms/3600000 - Math.trunc(ms/3600000))*60) + ((ms/3600000 - Math.trunc(ms/3600000))*60 % 1 != 0 ? 1 : 0)
})

console.log(msToTime(Math.abs(newDate-oldDate)))
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
    function update(datetime = "2017-01-01 05:11:58") {
        var theevent = new Date(datetime);
        now = new Date();
        var sec_num = (theevent - now) / 1000;
        var days    = Math.floor(sec_num / (3600 * 24));
        var hours   = Math.floor((sec_num - (days * (3600 * 24)))/3600);
        var minutes = Math.floor((sec_num - (days * (3600 * 24)) - (hours * 3600)) / 60);
        var seconds = Math.floor(sec_num - (days * (3600 * 24)) - (hours * 3600) - (minutes * 60));

        if (hours   < 10) {hours   = "0"+hours;}
        if (minutes < 10) {minutes = "0"+minutes;}
        if (seconds < 10) {seconds = "0"+seconds;}

        return  days+':'+ hours+':'+minutes+':'+seconds;
    }
    
   console.log(update())
```

Answer (score 2):

MomentJS has a function to do that:

```
const start = moment(j.timings.start);
const end = moment(j.timings.end);
const elapsedMinutes = end.diff(start, "minutes");
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's my take:

```js
    function timeSince(date, longText) {
        let seconds = null;
        let leadingText = null;

        if (date instanceof Date) {
            seconds = Math.floor((new Date() - date) / 1000);
            if (seconds < 0) {
                leadingText = " from now";
            } else {
                leadingText = " ago";
            }
            seconds = Math.abs(seconds);
        } else {
            seconds = date;
            leadingText = "";
        }

        const intervals = [
            [31536000, "year"  ],
            [ 2592000, "month" ],
            [   86400, "day"   ],
            [    3600, "hour"  ],
            [      60, "minute"],
            [       1, "second"],
        ];

        let interval = seconds;
        let intervalStrings = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < intervals.length; i++) {
            let divResult = Math.floor(interval / intervals[i][0]);
            if (divResult > 0) {
                intervalStrings.push(divResult + " " + intervals[i][1] + ((divResult > 1) ? "s" : ""));
                interval = interval % intervals[i][0];
                if (!longText) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        let intStr = intervalStrings.join(", ");

        return intStr + leadingText;
    }
    
    // Usage
    console.log(    timeSince(123456))
```

Comment: this is more accurate with singular and plural - second/second(s)

Answer (score 2):

Easy Way

```js
  function diff_hours(dt2, dt1) 
     {
    
      var diff =(dt2.getTime() - dt1.getTime()) / 1000;
      diff /= (60 * 60);
      return Math.abs(Math.round(diff));
    
     }
    
    
    function diff_minutes(dt2, dt1) 
     {
    
      var diff =(dt2.getTime() - dt1.getTime()) / 1000;
      diff /= (60);
      return Math.abs(Math.round(diff));
    
     }
    
    function diff_seconds(dt2, dt1) 
     {
    
      var diff =(dt2.getTime() - dt1.getTime()) / 1000;
      return Math.abs(Math.round(diff));
    
     }
    
    function diff_miliseconds(dt2, dt1) 
     {
    
      var diff =(dt2.getTime() - dt1.getTime());
      return Math.abs(Math.round(diff));
    
     }
    
    
    dt1 = new Date(2014,10,2);
    dt2 = new Date(2014,10,3);
    console.log(diff_hours(dt1, dt2));
    
    
    dt1 = new Date("October 13, 2014 08:11:00");
    dt2 = new Date("October 14, 2014 11:13:00");
    console.log(diff_hours(dt1, dt2));
    
    console.log(diff_minutes(dt1, dt2));
    
    console.log(diff_seconds(dt1, dt2));
    
    console.log(diff_miliseconds(dt1, dt2));
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
 function calculateExamRemainingTime(exam_end_at) {

    $(function(){

        const calcNewYear = setInterval(function(){

            const exam_ending_at    = new Date(exam_end_at);
            const current_time      = new Date();
           
            const totalSeconds     = Math.floor((exam_ending_at - (current_time))/1000);;
            const totalMinutes     = Math.floor(totalSeconds/60);
            const totalHours       = Math.floor(totalMinutes/60);
            const totalDays        = Math.floor(totalHours/24);

            const hours   = totalHours - ( totalDays * 24 );
            const minutes = totalMinutes - ( totalDays * 24 * 60 ) - ( hours * 60 );
            const seconds = totalSeconds - ( totalDays * 24 * 60 * 60 ) - ( hours * 60 * 60 ) - ( minutes * 60 );

            const examRemainingHoursSection = document.querySelector('#remainingHours');
            const examRemainingMinutesSection = document.querySelector('#remainingMinutes');
            const examRemainingSecondsSection = document.querySelector('#remainingSeconds');

            examRemainingHoursSection.innerHTML = hours.toString();
            examRemainingMinutesSection.innerHTML = minutes.toString();
            examRemainingSecondsSection.innerHTML = seconds.toString();

        },1000);
    });
    }
    
    calculateExamRemainingTime('2025-06-03 20:20:20');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="remainingHours">
</div>
<div id="remainingMinutes">
</div>
<div id="remainingSeconds">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const arrDiff = [
  {
    label: 'second',
    value: 1000,
  },
  {
    label: 'minute',
    value: 1000 * 60,
  },
  {
    label: 'hour',
    value: 1000 * 60 * 60,
  },
  {
    label: 'day',
    value: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
  },
  {
    label: 'year',
    value: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365,
  },
];

function diff(date) {
  let result = { label: '', value: '' };
  const value = Date.now() - date;
  for (let obj of arrDiff) {
    let temp = Math.round(value / obj.value);
    if (temp === 0) {
      break;
    } else
      result = {
        value: temp,
        label: obj.label,
      };
  }
  return result;
}

const postDate = new Date('2020-12-17 23:50:00+0700');
console.log(diff(postDate));
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you added comments to your code to explain what's going on, rather than just putting up code.

Answer (score 1):

#### 2021 version

*Inspired with [Alnitak's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13904120/12496886) and [RienNeVaPlus's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32514236/12496886) answers.*

Calculates since and until automatically (see examples below).

```js
const timeUnits = {
  year: 31536e6,
  month: 2592e6,
  week: 6048e5,
  day: 864e5,
  hour: 36e5,
  minute: 6e4,
  second: 1e3,
};

const timeUnitsNamesShort = {
  year: 'y',
  month: 'm',
  week: 'w',
  day: 'd',
  hour: 'h',
  minute: 'm',
  second: 's',
};

const isFuture = (date) => date > Date.now();

const dateDiffStructure = (date, units = timeUnits) => {
  let delta = Math.abs(date - Date.now());
  return Object.entries(units).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
      acc[key] = Math.floor(delta / value);
      delta -= acc[key] * value;
      return acc;
  }, {});
};

const dateDiffStructureToString = (date, diffStructure, values, short) => {
  const diffStructureEntries = values 
    ? Object.entries(diffStructure).filter(([key, value]) => values.includes(key) && value)
    : Object.entries(diffStructure).filter(([, value]) => value);
  if (!diffStructureEntries.length) return 'just now';
  const suffix = isFuture(date) ? 'left' : 'ago';
  const diffString = diffStructureEntries.reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
      const timeUnit = short
          ? timeUnitsNamesShort[key]
          : value > 1
              ? ` ${key}s`
              : ` ${key}`;
      acc = acc ? `${acc} ` : '';
      return `${acc}${value}${timeUnit}`;
  }, '');
  return `${diffString} ${suffix}`;
};

const getDateDiff = (date, values, short) => {
  const diffStructure = dateDiffStructure(date);
  return dateDiffStructureToString(date, diffStructure, values, short);
};
```

Tests and examples:

```js
const timeUnits = {
  year: 31536e6,
  month: 2592e6,
  week: 6048e5,
  day: 864e5,
  hour: 36e5,
  minute: 6e4,
  second: 1e3,
};

const timeUnitsNamesShort = {
  year: 'y',
  month: 'm',
  week: 'w',
  day: 'd',
  hour: 'h',
  minute: 'm',
  second: 's',
};

const isFuture = (date) => date > Date.now();

const dateDiffStructure = (date, units = timeUnits) => {
  let delta = Math.abs(date - Date.now());
  return Object.entries(units).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
    acc[key] = Math.floor(delta / value);
    delta -= acc[key] * value;
    return acc;
  }, {});
};

const dateDiffStructureToString = (date, diffStructure, values, short) => {
  const diffStructureEntries = values ?
    Object.entries(diffStructure).filter(([key, value]) => values.includes(key) && value) :
    Object.entries(diffStructure).filter(([, value]) => value);
  if (!diffStructureEntries.length) return 'just now';
  const suffix = isFuture(date) ? 'left' : 'ago';
  const diffString = diffStructureEntries.reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
    const timeUnit = short ?
      timeUnitsNamesShort[key] :
      value > 1 ?
      ` ${key}s` :
      ` ${key}`;
    acc = acc ? `${acc} ` : '';
    return `${acc}${value}${timeUnit}`;
  }, '');
  return `${diffString} ${suffix}`;
};

const getDateDiff = (date, values, short) => {
  const diffStructure = dateDiffStructure(date);
  console.log(`dateDiffStructure(${JSON.stringify(date)}) //`, diffStructure);
  return dateDiffStructureToString(date, diffStructure, values, short);
};

const tests = [
  ['After tomorrow', [new Date(Date.now() + 8.64e7 + 1e6)]],
  ['Yesterday', [new Date(Date.now() - 8.64e7)]],
  ['Past', [new Date(Date.now() * Math.random())]],
  ['Future short', [new Date(Date.now() * (Math.random() + 1)), ['year', 'month', 'day'], true]],
  ['Now', [Date.now()]]
];

tests.forEach(([text, args]) => {
  console.log(`${text}:`);
  console.group();
  console.log(`getDateDiff(${args.map(item => JSON.stringify(item)).join(', ')}) //`, getDateDiff(...args));
  console.groupEnd();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function getTimeRemaining(endtime){
  const total = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
  const seconds = Math.floor( (total/1000) % 60 );
  const minutes = Math.floor( (total/1000/60) % 60 );
  const hours = Math.floor( (total/(1000*60*60)) % 24 );
  const days = Math.floor( total/(1000*60*60*24) );

  return {
    total,
    days,
    hours,
    minutes,
    seconds
  };
}

let result = getTimeRemaining(endTime) // pass the end date into the func
```

you can also find out the diff between two dates time by easily change the func parameters to

```js
function getTimeRemaining(endtime,startime){
  const total = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(startime);
  const seconds = Math.floor( (total/1000) % 60 );
  const minutes = Math.floor( (total/1000/60) % 60 );
  const hours = Math.floor( (total/(1000*60*60)) % 24 );
  const days = Math.floor( total/(1000*60*60*24) );

  return {
    total,
    days,
    hours,
    minutes,
    seconds
  };
}

var endTime = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 100000);
var startTime = new Date();

let result = getTimeRemaining(endTime,startTime) 
console.dir(result)
```

The result will be like

days: 0,
hours: 1,
minutes: 0,
seconds: 0,
total: 3600000

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

here is an code to find difference between two dates in Days,Hours,Minutes,Seconds (assuming the future date is new year date).

```js
var one_day = 24*60*60*1000;              // total milliseconds in one day

var today = new Date();
var new_year = new Date("01/01/2017");    // future date

var today_time = today.getTime();         // time in miliiseconds
var new_year_time = new_year.getTime();                         

var time_diff = Math.abs(new_year_time - today_time);  //time diff in ms  
var days = Math.floor(time_diff / one_day);            // no of days

var remaining_time = time_diff - (days*one_day);      // remaining ms  

var hours = Math.floor(remaining_time/(60*60*1000));   
remaining_time = remaining_time - (hours*60*60*1000);  

var minutes = Math.floor(remaining_time/(60*1000));        
remaining_time = remaining_time - (minutes * 60 * 1000);   

var seconds = Math.ceil(remaining_time / 1000);   
console.log("Days: " + days + " Hours: " + hours + " Minutes: " + minutes + " Seconds: " + seconds);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let delta = Math.floor(Math.abs(start.getTime() - end.getTime()) / 1000);
let hours = Math.floor(delta / 3600);
delta -= hours * 3600;
let minutes = Math.floor(delta / 60);
delta -= minutes * 60;
let seconds = delta;
if (hours.toString().length === 1) {
  hours = `0${hours}`;
}
if (minutes.toString().length === 1) {
  minutes = `0${minutes}`;
}
if (seconds.toString().length === 1) {
  seconds = `0${seconds}`;
}
const recordingTime = `${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds}`;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here’s [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13904120/537998) in TypeScript without mutation. Also has a 2-digit seconds handler.

```js
const maybeAddLeadingZero = (number: number): string => [String(number).length === 1 ? '0' : '', number].join('');

const timeRemaining = (endDate: Date): string => {
  const deltaInSeconds = Math.abs(Date.now() - endDate.valueOf()) / 1000;

  const days = Math.floor(deltaInSeconds / 86400);
  const deltaMinusDaysInSeconds = deltaInSeconds - days * 86400;

  const hours = Math.floor(deltaMinusDaysInSeconds / 3600) % 24;
  const deltaMinusHoursInSeconds = deltaMinusDaysInSeconds - hours * 3600;

  const minutes = Math.floor(deltaMinusHoursInSeconds / 60) % 60;
  const twoDigitMinutes = maybeAddLeadingZero(minutes);
  const deltaMinusMinutesInSeconds = deltaMinusHoursInSeconds - minutes * 60;

  const seconds = Math.floor(deltaMinusMinutesInSeconds % 60);
  const twoDigitSeconds = maybeAddLeadingZero(seconds);

  return `${hours}:${twoDigitMinutes}:${twoDigitSeconds}`
}

const twentyFourHoursInTheFuture = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)

// example implementation
setInterval(() => {
  const deriveTimeRemaining = timeRemaining(twentyFourHoursInTheFuture);

  document.body.innerHTML = "";
  document.write(`<h1>${deriveTimeRemaining}</h1>`)
}, 1000 / 60) // 60 FPS
```

Comment: somehow if you add 29 days to current date - then the diff is `28 days, 23 hours 59 minutes 59 seconds`, but if you add 30 days, then the diff is `30 days, 0 hours 59 minutes 59 seconds`. I.e. one extra hour is added. Something is wrong with this and the other answers.. `const dataAvailableToDate = new Date()
dataAvailableToDate.setDate(dataAvailableToDate.getDate() + 30)`

Answer (score -1):

**We can do it by simple method**

```js
/*Declare the function */
function Clock(){
    let d1 = new Date("1 Jan 2021");
    let d2 = new Date();

    let difference = Math.abs(d1 - d2); //to get absolute value
    //calculate for each one
    let Days = Math.floor(difference / ( 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 ));
    let Hours = Math.floor((difference / ( 1000 * 60 * 60 )) % 24);
    let Mins = Math.floor((difference / ( 1000 * 60 )) % 60);
    let Seconds = Math.floor((difference / ( 1000 )) % 60);

    //getting nodes and change the text inside
    let getday = document.querySelector(".big_text_days");
    let gethour = document.querySelector(".big_text_hours");
    let getmins = document.querySelector(".big_text_mins");
    let getsec = document.querySelector(".big_text_sec");

    getday.textContent = Check_Zero(Days); 
    gethour.textContent = Check_Zero(Hours);
    getmins.textContent = Check_Zero(Mins)
    getsec.textContent = Check_Zero(Seconds);
}

//call the funcion for every 1 second
setInterval(Clock , 1000);


//check and add zero in front, if it is lessthan 10
function Check_Zero(mytime){
    return mytime < 10 ? "0"+mytime : mytime;

}
```

```css
*{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
    max-width: 900px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    background-color:whitesmoke;
    background-size: cover;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: 5rem;
}
.main_container{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
}
h1{
    font-size: 3rem;
    color: #3D4B72;
}
.big_text_days , .big_text_hours , .big_text_mins , .big_text_sec{
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 2;
    color: #AC7591;
    text-align: center;
}
p{
    padding: 20px 0px 20px 0px;
    font-size: 3rem;
    text-align: center;
}
.spantext{
    color: #103c28;
    margin: 0px 3rem;
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-style: italic;
}
.text_sec{
    color : #005259;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="description" content="Responsive site">
        <meta name="keywords" content="HTML,CSS,JS">
        <meta name="author" content="Ranjan">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <title>Home</title>

        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alfa+Slab+One|Bree+Serif|Exo|Exo+2|Lato|Mansalva|Playfair+Display&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
       
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

    <body>
        
    <section>
      <h1>CountDown Timer</h1>
        </section>
                
         <section>
          <div class="main_container">
                
            <div class="days_container">
             <p class="big_text_days">1</p>
              <span class="spantext spantextdays">Days</span>
            </div>
    
            <div class="hours_container">
             <p class="big_text_hours">1</p>
              <span class="spantext spantexthours">Hours</span>
            </div>
    
            <div class="mins_container">
             <p class="big_text_mins">1</p>
              <span class="spantext spantextmins">Minutes</span>
            </div>
            
            <div class="sec_container">
             <p class="big_text_sec text_sec">1</p>
              <span class="spantext spantextsec">Seconds</span>
            </div>
         </div>
        </section>

    </body>
</html>
```