# Calculate date+time range

Tags: jquery

Sorry if Duplicate But could not Find anything Similar that can help me.

I am using [datetime picker](http://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/)

And I am trying to calculate a date range based on Day + time

Till now I came with this
In JS

```
$('#calculate').click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var darrival = $('#darrival').val();
  var rdate = $('#rdate').val();
  var start = new Date(darrival);
  var end= new Date(rdate);
  var finaltime=(end-start)/1000/60/60;
  alert(finaltime);
});
```

But I am getting NaN.
I made

```
console.log(start)
```

And it show up "Invalid Date"

The value that I am taking(`var darrival = $('#darrival').val();`)
Look like: **26-08-2013 01:08**

I guess new Date doesnt count the time can anybody suggest something?
thank you forrward.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13903897/javascript-return-number-of-days-hours-minutes-seconds-between-two-dates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to change more then one thing in your code ..

```
1) you need specify language and format while building datetimepicker

2) you need to get data using datpicker's api not using the textbox
```

pls see my below example this might help you

```
<body>

    <div class="well">

      <div id="rdate" class="input-append date">
        <input data-format="dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss" type="text" id="date1"></input>
        <span class="add-on">
          <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar">
          </i>
        </span>
      </div>


        <div id="darrival" class="input-append">
            <input data-format="dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss" type="text"  id="date2"></input>
            <span class="add-on">
                <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar">
                </i>
            </span>
        </div>



    </div>

    <input type='button' name='calculate' id='calculate' value='click this' onclick='fn1()'>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function() {
        $('#darrival').datetimepicker({
            format: 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss',
            language: 'pt-BR'
        });

        $('#rdate').datetimepicker({
            format: 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss',
            language: 'pt-BR'
        });


      });
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $('#calculate').click(function(event){

          event.preventDefault();
          var picker1 = $('#darrival').data('datetimepicker');
          var picker2 = $('#rdate').data('datetimepicker');
          var start = new Date(picker1.getDate());
          var end= new Date(picker2.getDate());
          var finaltime=(end-start)/1000/60/60;
          alert(finaltime);

        });
    </script>

</body>
```

Comment: Using ur example I was coming `TypeError: Cannot call method 'getDate' of undefined ` Error so I did it as following: var darrival = $('#darrival').val(); var rdate = $('#rdate').val(); var start= new Date(darrival); var end= new Date(rdate); var finaltime=(end - start) / 1000 / 60 / 60; alert(finaltime); **Fixed changed data format from:26-08-2013 01:08
2013-08-26 01:08**

Answer (score 1):

You can use [moment.js difference method](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/) to calculate the date range.