# Moment.js Duration between Two Dates

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs, date-difference

How do I get the time difference between two different dates variables, specifically in years, months and days using moment.js?

I found this method but I keep getting weird results. Sometimes the result is one month ahead so I added a subtract one months part to make the result correct, but when the difference between the two dates can be divided into whole years it then becomes a month behind, but then if I remove the subtract month part, it gets even more out of whack.

Also I would like to format it as "X Years, Y Months, Z days", but also can't figure out how to format it in such way.

```js
var dateOne = new Date(2000,07,16);
var dateTwo = new Date (1990,07,16);
var updatedDate = moment(dateOne).format('ll');
   
var x = moment(dateOne, 'DD/MM/YYYY').diff(moment(dateTwo, 'DD/MM/YYYY'))
var y = moment.duration(x);
var why = moment(x).subtract(1, 'M');
var z = Math.floor(y.asYears()) + moment.utc(why).format('/MM/DD');
console.log(z);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13903897/javascript-return-number-of-days-hours-minutes-seconds-between-two-dates/32514236#32514236)

Comment: You are doing something weird. For one thing, dates and durations are completely different things, you can't format a duration as a date. For another, the difference between those two is exactly 10 years: `moment(dateOne).diff(dateTwo, 'years', true)`

Comment: There is no reason to include jQuery. *dateOne* is a Date object, so no need for the second argument in `moment(dateOne, 'DD/MM/YYYY')`. You can include moment.js as an external library using a CDN, e.g. `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js`

Answer (score 1):

Try this perhaps?

```
var firstDate = moment();
var secondDate = moment("2018-03-19");
var yearDiff = firstDate.diff(secondDate, "year");
var monthDiff = firstDate.diff(secondDate, "month");
var dayDiff = firstDate.diff(secondDate, "day");
console.log(yearDiff + " Years, " + monthDiff + " Months, " + dayDiff + " Days");
```

https://jsfiddle.net/px1brLdk/

Comment: A good answer should explain why the OP has their issue and how your code fixes it. Also, you can post your code as a runnable snippet and include external libraries. If you do that, you'll find that the values are the total difference for each interval so on 2019-02-21 you'll get 0 years, 11 months, 339 days.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by others in the comments, you can't format a duration as a date and since `dateOne` and `dateTwo` are a Date objects, there is no need for the second argument in `moment(dateOne, 'DD/MM/YYYY')`, simply use [`moment(Date)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/date/).

Moverover, please note that when you use `new Date(year, monthIndex, day)` `monthIndex` starts from 0, see [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date):

> The argument `monthIndex` is 0-based. This means that `January = 0` and `December = 11`.

You can use [moment-duration-format](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/plugins/duration-format/) plug-in to format momentjs duration according your needs, see [`format()`](https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format#template) docs on the [plug-in page](https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format).

Here a live sample:

```js
var dateOne = new Date(2000, 7, 16);
var dateTwo = new Date(1990, 7, 16);

var diff = moment(dateOne).diff(moment(dateTwo))
var dur = moment.duration(diff);
var result = dur.format();
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-duration-format/2.2.2/moment-duration-format.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Moment is having a method called .diff() Use that one. 
https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/