# Getting duration between two dates in date-fns in days:hrs:mins:secs format

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datetime, date-fns

I'm trying to display a count-down timer using date-fns library and doing things the below way, unable to find the solution in react.

Expected output: 60 days : 8 hours : 9 minutes : 5 seconds remaining

```
    const finishTime = new Date("01/01/2020");
    const currentTime = new Date();
```

Adding results to array to traverse later:

```
    results.push(differenceInMonths(finishTime, currentTime));
    results.push(differenceInDays(finishTime, currentTime));
    results.push(differenceInHours(finishTime, currentTime));
    results.push(differenceInMinutes(finishTime, currentTime));
    results.push(differenceInSeconds(finishTime, currentTime));
```

Adding manual logic to get the time from seconds. There should obviously be a better logic wiht / without using the library, which I'm missing:

```
    const monthsRemaining = results[4] / (30 * 24 * 3600); // this will anyways fail as 30 days is not common for every month
    const daysRemaining = (monthsRemaining % 1) * 30;
    const hoursRemaining = (daysRemaining % 1) * 24;
    const minutesRemaining = (hoursRemaining % 1) * 60;
    const secondsRemaining = (minutesRemaining % 1) * 60;

return (
        <div>
            {Math.round(monthsRemaining)} Months : {Math.round(daysRemaining)}{" "}
            days : {Math.round(hoursRemaining)} hours :{" "}
            {Math.round(minutesRemaining)} minutes :{" "}
            {Math.round(secondsRemaining)} seconds
        </div>
    );
```

Any suggestions or pointers to the right methods, as I don't see such direct implementation, I could only see formatDistance method which only one unit

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52550254/4283738

Comment: Thanks @joyBlanks But what I was looking is for a solution using the date-fns library

Comment: Especially now, Moment has deprecated itself.

Comment: Btw, did you get your answer below? Feel free to accept it.

Answer (score 32):

intervalToDuration is what you are looking for.

```
// Get the duration between January 15, 1929 and April 4, 1968.
intervalToDuration({
  start: new Date(1929, 0, 15, 12, 0, 0),
   end: new Date(1968, 3, 4, 19, 5, 0)
})
// => { years: 39, months: 2, days: 20, hours: 7, minutes: 5, seconds: 0 }
```

https://date-fns.org/v2.16.1/docs/intervalToDuration

Comment: This doesn't answer the question precisely. OP asked "Expected output: 60 days : 8 hours : 9 minutes : 5 seconds remaining" and `intervalToDuration` would not return 60 days, but rather 1 month and 30 days or 2 months.

Comment: This is not the solution.

Answer (score 4):

As pointed out above, there's not an exact answer here. For those who came to this thread looking for one, you can combine `intervalToDuration` with `differenceInDays` to get the required result.

```
// Get the duration between Nov 2, 2019 and Jan 1, 2020.
const start = new Date(2019, 10, 2, 12, 0, 0);
const end = new Date(2020, 0, 1, 20, 9, 5);

const { hours, minutes, seconds } = intervalToDuration({ start, end });
// => { years: 0, months: 1, days: 30, hours: 8, minutes: 9, seconds: 5 }

const days = differenceInDays(end, start);
// => 60

console.log(`${days} days : ${hours} hours : ${minutes} minutes : ${seconds} seconds remaining`);
```

https://date-fns.org/v2.30.0/docs/intervalToDuration

https://date-fns.org/v2.30.0/docs/differenceInDays

Answer (score 3):

In this case you need to use formatDistance.

1. Import formatDistance from date-fns:

   ```
   import { formatDistance } from 'date-fns'
   ```
2. Use the property with something like this:

   ```
   formatDistance(firstDate, secondDate, [options])
   ```

As options, you can include, for example, the language "locale: es".

Comment: The problem with this is it returns a string of text, rather than a breakdown of duration. For example, if you wanted the number of days for a date span that is over many months