# How do i find the number of days between two formatted dates in react Javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, datetime, datetime-format

Does anyone know how to find the difference in days between these two dates?:

```
import { format } from 'date-fns'

const formattedStartDate = format(new Date(startDate), 'dd MMMM yyyy');
const formattedEndDate = format(new Date(endDate), 'dd MMMM yyyy');
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/41960/12119713 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/13903897/12119713