# Subtract two date variables and get in terms of days in javascript

Tags: javascript

Here is my code.

```
var today = new Date();
var reqDate = new Date(today.getFullYear(),today.getMonth()-3, today.getDate());
var day = today-reqDate;
```

I want the 'day' should be something around 90; but it gives as some long integer.

Comment: There are entire Stack Overflow threads devoted to this question. Here are some of them: 1) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/542938/how-do-i-get-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates-in-javascript 2) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224834/get-difference-between-2-dates-in-javascript 3) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41948/how-do-i-get-the-difference-between-two-dates-in-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The long integer is the number of milliseconds since midnight Jan 1, 1970. So in order to get the number of days you need to divide it. Code below:

```
var days = day/(1000*60*60*24);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have got value in day variable as milliseconds, so divide it by 1000*60*60*24 to get day count.

Another thing, it will be a decimal value.

So you have to discard fraction value using `floor` function.

```
var days = Math.floor(day/(1000*60*60*24));
```