# String date to System date compare

Tags: javascript

I have two dates , first date is string coming from input text like 01-01-2011(dd-MM-yyyy) and second date is current date or system date(new Date()).

I have to compare the input date to current date(gretter or equal). I'm facing issue of NaN and did not find efficient help in google.

Any help will be appreciate.

Comment: What does the string look like? That date is obviously invalid. What does your code look like?

Comment: your input text is wrong

Comment: the date string is like this 01-01-2011(dd-MM-yyyy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with the below code snippet.

```
var from = "13-05-2014".split("-");
var dt1 = new Date(from[2], from[1] - 1, from[0]);
var dt2 = new Date();
if (dt1 - dt2 > 0) {
    alert("current or future date");
}
```

If you want difference in detail format then please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17732897/difference-between-two-dates-in-years-months-days-in-javascript) link.

Answer (score 0):

```
var date=new Date();
var today= date.getDate()+"-"+(date.getMonth()-1)+"-"+date.getFullYear();
```

and compare with this date

or
make two dates and use this method

```
function datediff(date1, date2) {
    var y1 = date1.getFullYear();
    var m1 = date1.getMonth();
    var d1 = date1.getDate();
    var y2 = date2.getFullYear();
    var m2 = date2.getMonth();
    var d2 = date2.getDate();
    if (d1 < d2) {
        m1--;
        var date=new Date(y2, m2, 1, 12);
        date.setDate(0);
        d1 += date.getDate();
    }
    if (m1 < m2) {
        y1--;
        m1 += 12;
    }
    return [y1 - y2, m1 - m2, d1 - d2];
}
```

if it returned [0,0,0] two dates are equal

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>

Date.prototype.format=function(){
    var year=this.getFullYear();
    var month=this.getMonth();
    var date=this.getDate();
    return year+"-"+month+"-"+date;
}

var usrdate=new Date();
usrdate.setFullYear(2014,4,13);
usrdate=usrdate.format();

function compare(usrdate)
{
    var sysdate=new Date().format();
    if(sysdate>usrdate)
       alert("System Date is greater");
    else if(sysdate<usrdate)
       alert("User Date is greater");
    else
       alert("Both date is equal");
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<p onclick="compare(usrdate);">Compare Date </p> 
</body>
</html>
```