# Correct way to get the difference between Date objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript

This is a very common question, however I wasn't able to find a correct answer. I have the following:

```
tcom
Mon Dec 14 2015 12:22:28 GMT-0500 (PET)
treq
Mon Dec 14 2015 12:18:27 GMT-0500 (PET)

tcom - treq
241122
tdif = new Date(tcom - treq);
Wed Dec 31 1969 19:04:01 GMT-0500 (PET)
```

I've seen answers like this:[Get difference between 2 dates in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224834/get-difference-between-2-dates-in-javascript) but that is a fixed method, I don't know beforehand if the difference is going to be days, hours, minutes or seconds.

Thanks

Comment: `tcom - treq` <--- this is the difference between 2 dates. Anything wrong with it?

Comment: Well, `241122` ms *is* the difference between those two datetimes. What exactly are you asking for?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/17732897/1048572, http://stackoverflow.com/q/18623783/1048572 or some other

Answer (score 0):

You are returned with a difference in miliseconds, so do some math calc here.
1 day = 24 x 60 x 60 x 10 = 864000 miliseconds.

Comment: "1 day = 24 x 60 x 60 x 10 = 864000 miliseconds" --- unless when it's not

Answer (score 0):

Yes, subtracting two Date objects is a correct way to find their difference in milliseconds.

The following are equivalent:

```
date1 - date2
date1.getTime() - date2.getTime()
```

If you want to convert the result to years, months, days, etc., you can create a new Date object at epoch with the millisecond part set to the offset that you've obtained. e.g.:

```
var start = new Date();

// some time passes...

var end = new Date();

var elapsedMillis = end - start;

var elapsed = new Date(1970, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, elapsedMillis);
```

Then you can use methods like `getMinutes()`, `getSeconds()` etc. to get the components you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to get the difference in **a number of different units**, you can use a function that takes an enumerated value, like:

```
var Units = {
    MS: 1,
    SEC: 1000,
    MIN: 1000 * 60,
    HOUR: 1000 * 60 * 60,
    DAY: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
    YEAR: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365
};

function getDateDiff( a, b, unit ) {
    return (a - b) / unit;
}
```

Then you can call it easily:

```
getDateDiff( date1, date2, Units.HOUR );
```

If you only need it in ms though, then a simple subtraction is your best friend.