# Counting down days left to a date?

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble using a function with JS.
I got this JS code from here [Difference between two dates in years, months, days in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17732897/difference-between-two-dates-in-years-months-days-in-javascript?rq=1)

The months work fine but when I try to call the days it doesn't seem to work right, it will show 30 days when it should be 24. can anyone see anything wrong with the code?

```
    function monthDiff(d1, d2) {
        var months;
        months = (d2.getFullYear() - d1.getFullYear()) * 12;
        months -= d1.getMonth() + 1;
        months += d2.getMonth();
        return months <= 0 ? 0 : months;
    }
    function daysInMonth(date) {
        return new Date(date.getYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 0).getDate();
    }    
function diffDate(date1, date2) {
    if (date2 && date2.getTime() && !isNaN(date2.getTime())) {
        var months = monthDiff(d1, d2);
        var days = 0;

        if (date1.getUTCDate() >= date2.getUTCDate()) {
            days = date1.getUTCDate() - date2.getUTCDate();
        }
        else {
            months--;
            days = date1.getUTCDate() - date2.getUTCDate() + daysInMonth(date2);
        }

        // Use the variables months and days how you need them.
    }
}
```

Here's the var that uses the functions

```
var     months = monthDiff(new Date(), options.timestamp ) % 12 + 1,
        days = daysInMonth(new Date()),
```

Comment: I think I should be using the diffDate instead of daysInMonth but when I do it that way it will only show 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## I think that you might use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com)

Don't reinvent the wheel again.

Just plug [Moment.js Date Range Plugin](https://github.com/codebox/moment-precise-range).

---

## Example:

```js
var starts = moment('2014-02-03 12:53:12');
var ends   = moment();

var duration = moment.duration(ends.diff(starts));

// with ###moment precise date range plugin###
// it will tell you the difference in human terms

var diff = moment.preciseDiff(starts, ends, true); 
// example: { "years": 2, "months": 7, "days": 0, "hours": 6, "minutes": 29, "seconds": 17, "firstDateWasLater":  false }


// or as string:
var diffHuman = moment.preciseDiff(starts, ends);
// example: 2 years 7 months 6 hours 29 minutes 17 seconds

document.getElementById('output1').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(diff)
document.getElementById('output2').innerHTML = diffHuman
```

```html
<html>
<head>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.14.1/moment.min.js"></script>

  <script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/codebox/moment-precise-range/master/moment-precise-range.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  
  <h2>Difference between "NOW and 2014-02-03 12:53:12"</h2>
  <span id="output1"></span>
  <br />
  <span id="output2"></span>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I did consider using moment.js, but doesn't it have a limit with showing Years Months and Days at the same time?

Comment: You mean formatting? If so, no it doesn't. I've been using it for years with joy.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17732897/difference-between-two-dates-in-years-months-days-in-javascript?rq=1 This question says that you can only use it for Days or years or months not all three? Is that formatting?

Comment: That explanation in the question is wrong. Aren't you asking the day difference? What's your goal?

Comment: All of the solutions here are trying to find the day difference, how're they different?

Comment: The goal is the same as in the link I provided. To show the amount of years(total years) months(months left within the years) and days(days left until the end of the month) So it would show eg: 2 years 6 months and 10 days
I was having trouble specifically with getting the days to work though.

Comment: Not 2 years 24 months and 550 days.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122581/discussion-between-inanc-and-krypton).

Comment: @Krypton I updated the code according to your needs with a working example, best.

Comment: @Krypton Is it OK?

Comment: Seems to be, but I'm having trouble including the data. could you have a look at the chat log? the code I've tried is there :)

Comment: @Krypton I'm on there right now :)

Answer (score 6):

Try this code which is short, easy and accurate:

```
var _MS_PER_DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;

// a and b are javascript Date objects
var a = new Date("7/13/2010");
var b = new Date("12/15/2010");

function dateDiffInDays(a, b) {
  // Discard the time and time-zone information.
  var utc1 = Date.UTC(a.getFullYear(), a.getMonth(), a.getDate());
  var utc2 = Date.UTC(b.getFullYear(), b.getMonth(), b.getDate());

  return Math.round((utc2 - utc1) / _MS_PER_DAY);
}
```

Comment: Good idea. You will have a small problem on days when the time switches from DST to standard. On those days `utc2 - utc1` might give 23 or 25 hours. You can take care of that case by using `Math.round` instead of `Math.floor`.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion @redneb I will update my code accordingly

Comment: Great answer and works great, however it counted the total number of days not the days remaining from months and years.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function that will return the difference expressed in number of years, months and days:

```js
function dateDiff(d1, d2) {
    var years = 0, months = 0, days = 0, arr;
    if (d1 > d2) { // call inverse
        interval = dateDiff(d2, d1);
        return {
            years: -interval.years, 
            months: -interval.months, 
            days: -interval.days
        };
    }
    days = d2.getDate() - d1.getDate();
    if (days < 0) {
        months--;
        days+= new Date(new Date(d2).setDate(0)).getDate();
    }
    months += d2.getMonth() - d1.getMonth();
    if (months < 0) {
        years--;
        months+=12;
    }
    years += d2.getFullYear() - d1.getFullYear();
    return {
        years: years, 
        months: months,
        days: days
    };
}

// Sample data
var d1 = new Date('2013-10-20');
var d2 = new Date('2016-12-16')
// Call
var interval = dateDiff(d1, d2);
// Output each number separately
console.log('Years: ', interval.years);
console.log('Months: ', interval.months);
console.log('Days: ', interval.days);
```

Comment: I think this is going to solve my problem but how would I use the data days, months, years individually? instead of all at once?

Comment: The function returns an object with three properties. Just use the property that you need. Like `interval.years`.

Comment: Awesome :). This is probably a simple question but how would I get the value without the 'months:'  part?

Comment: How do you mean? You want the `days` to be something like 266 without splitting into months?

Comment: Or do you mean `console.log(interval.years, interval.days)`? It would not be an accurate representation if you would just drop the months part of course.

Comment: No it calculates everything right :) but when running the snipped it shows 
years: xxx 
months: xxx
days: xxx
How would you just show the xxx? Thanks for your help as well, I've accepted your answer :)

Comment: The var that I'm using it in needs just the digits, does that make sense? Couldn't figure out why it wasn't working then I run the code and I'm like OH that's why!

Comment: Well, like I said above, this is just a matter of working with an object. Just use the properties to get the numbers. I updated the snippet to show you how you can show the individual numbers.

Comment: Ah, I see! I'm really new to JS and you've helped me a lot. THANK YOU!