# JavaScript: Display days, hours, minutes, and seconds until next birthday

Tags: javascript

I am trying to display days, hours, minutes, and seconds until next birthday. Birthday is calculated by prompt value. I have calculated seconds, minutes, hours and days. But I am getting wrong value e.g. "0". What's wrong in my code?

code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>

    p{
        text-align: center;
        font-family: monospace;
        font-size: 20px;
    }
    </style>
    <title>trail</title>

</head>
<body>
    <h1 style="text-align: center; font-family: monospace;"> My age </h1>
    <p id="dateField"> </p>
    <p id="birthField"> </p>
    <p id="nextBirth"> </p>

    <script>    

        var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
          "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
        ];

        var days = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];

        var today = new Date(); 

        var myMonth = prompt("What month were you born in?");
        var myDay = prompt("What day were you born on?");
        var myYear = prompt("What year were you born in?");

        var birthday = new Date(myYear, myMonth, myDay);  

        var dateLoc = document.getElementById("dateField").innerHTML = "Today is " + today;

        var birthField = document.getElementById("birthField")
        .innerHTML = "I was born on " + monthNames[myMonth - 1] + ' ' + myDay + ',' + myYear + '.' 
        + '(' + myMonth + '/' + myDay + '/' + myYear + ')';

        var years = today.getFullYear() - birthday.getFullYear();  

        var seconds = Math.floor( (years/1000) % 60 );
        var minutes = Math.floor( (years/1000/60) % 60 );
        var hours = Math.floor( (years/(1000*60*60)) % 24 );
        var days = Math.floor( years/(1000*60*60*24) );

        var nextBirth = document.getElementById("nextBirth").innerHTML = "I am " + years + "  Years old, and will turn " + (years + 1 ) + " in:" + "<br>" + days + " days," + hours + "hours," + minutes + "minutes," + seconds + "seconds";
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"**of** next birthday"*? Do you mean *"until"* the next birthday?

Comment: Math logic needs some rethinking also. Have to subtract days before calculating hours , subtract hours before calculating minutes etc

Comment: I suppose the main problem you have is `var years = today.getFullYear() - birthday.getFullYear()`. This will be something like `2017 - 1992` which is `25`. Think about that in regards to `(years/1000) % 60`, etc

Comment: @Phil I want to calculate days, hours, minutes, seconds left for next bierthday

Comment: @Phil that gives me birth year which I already calculated.

Comment: Yes, but `Math.floor( (25/1000) % 60 )` is `0`. Seems you think `years` is a millisecond value or something but it is not

Comment: Suggestion....hard code some values instead of prompts while you debug

Comment: @charlietfl that's not even the start of it. Calculating the answer accurately, taking into account all daylight savings changes, leap seconds, etc just makes my head hurt. I suppose OP could go for a very generalised solution with all the usual assumptions about timespans

Comment: @Phil this is a homework question, and typically those conditions are ignored on homework assignments. It's literally called `lab14`

Comment: @AanandKainth surely going the extra mile could earn some extra credit :D

Comment: But maybe asking on Stack Overflow could give you "unextra" credit. ;)

Comment: consider using moment.js

Comment: @Doug I want to calculate without using of moment.js

Comment: If anyone can help.

Comment: We aren't a homework answering service. @Phil already pointed out your issue.  I'd try getting the difference in milliseconds and work up, rather than down from the difference in years.

Comment: 1. check if next bday is in this year or next year -> save year in var nextBdayYear

2. create a var nextBday = Date(nextBdayYear, myMonth, myDay)

3. create a var today = Date.now();

4. create var diff = nextBday.getTime() - now
5. **use diff value for your calculations** and not your var years

Comment: @Andrea birth date is not fixed. it depends upon user entered value in prompt. I already created the steps you mentioned.

Comment: @Riya in your code your are using 'years' for calcs, not 'diff'

Comment: @Andres I just need to follow steps given by you ?

Comment: Probalby a duplicate of [*Difference between two dates in years, months, days in JavaScript*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17732897/difference-between-two-dates-in-years-months-days-in-javascript).

Answer (score 0):

(Not accounting for leap years/seconds, etc.)

Using `new Date()` the month passed starts at 0 for January. You could use:

```
var myMonth = prompt("What month were you born in?") - 1;
```

Now your variable `birthday` will store the correct month.

For `birthField` you can then change `monthNames[my Month - 1]` to `monthNames[my Month]`

For `years` you are only subtracting the birth year from the current year. If one's birthday hasn't occurred yet this year, `years` will be off. We will resolve this later.

We need to figure out the correct date for the user's next birthday. It is either this year or next year. It might be handy to store the date of their birthday this year in a variable:

```
var thisYearsBirthday = new Date(today.getFullYear(), myMonth, myDay);
```

We could then store a variable for the year of the user's upcoming birthday, assuming that it is next year:

```
var nextBirthdayYear = today.getFullYear() + 1;
```

Then we could check if `thisYearsBirthday` is in the future, and if so change `nextBirthdayYear` to be this year. We should also change `years` to reflect that the user's birthday hasn't happened yet this year.

```
if ( today < thisYearsBirthday ) {
  nextBirthdayYear = today.getFullYear();
  years = years - 1;
}
```

Now we can store the user's correct next birthday:

```
var nextBirthday = new Date( nextBirthdayYear, myMonth, myDay );
```

We can store how many milliseconds are left until the user's next birthday:

```
var milliseconds = nextBirthday - today;
```

Your variables `seconds`, `minutes`, `hours` and `days` are not formulas based on years, they are base on milliseconds. We should put the `milliseconds` variable in there:

```
var seconds = Math.floor( (milliseconds/1000) % 60 );
var minutes = Math.floor( (milliseconds/1000/60) % 60 );
var hours = Math.floor( (milliseconds/(1000*60*60)) % 24 );
var days = Math.floor( milliseconds/(1000*60*60*24) );
```

This should result in the correct days, hours, minutes, and seconds until next birthday being displayed.

Comment: There was an issue in my code where if the user's birthday was in the next day or two, the age displayed might be a year too old. To resolve this, I changed the `years` declaration back to what you originally had, and then adjusted `years` in the if statement that checks if the user's birthday has happened yet this year. I have edited the answer above.

Answer (score -1):

Hi You are missing that calculating next birthday that it should be below code

```
myMonth--;
var nextBirthday = (new Date(today.getFullYear(), myMonth, myDay))<today?(new Date(today.getFullYear()+1, myMonth, myDay)):(new Date(today.getFullYear(), myMonth, myDay))
```

And you can find working code below

```
var today = new Date();

var myMonth = prompt("What month were you born in?");
var myDay = prompt("What day were you born on?");
var myYear = prompt("What year were you born in?");

var birthday = new Date(myYear, myMonth, myDay);
console.log(birthday);

var dateLoc = document.getElementById("dateField").innerHTML = "Today is " + today;

var birthField = document.getElementById("birthField")
    .innerHTML = "I was born on " + monthNames[myMonth - 1] + ' ' + myDay + ',' + myYear + '.'
    + '(' + myMonth + '/' + myDay + '/' + myYear + ')';

var milliseconds,seconds,minutes,hours,days;

var years = today.getFullYear() - birthday.getFullYear();

//Here is my code 
 myMonth--;// Because of Month index is 0-11
var nextBirthday = (new Date(today.getFullYear(), myMonth, myDay))<today?(new Date(today.getFullYear()+1, myMonth, myDay)):(new Date(today.getFullYear(), myMonth, myDay)) //checking is passed or not
var diff = nextBirthday-today;

milliseconds=diff%1000;
diff=(diff-(milliseconds))/1000;
console.log(diff);
seconds=diff%60
console.log(diff);
diff=(diff-seconds)/60;
console.log(diff);
minutes=diff%60
diff=(diff-minutes)/60;
console.log(diff);
hours=diff%24
days=(diff-hours)/24;
console.log(diff);

var nextBirth = document.getElementById("nextBirth").innerHTML = "I am " + years + "  Years old, and will turn " + (years + 1 ) + " in:" + "<br>" + days + " days," + hours + "hours," + minutes + "minutes," + seconds + "seconds";
```

Comment: As below: you are assuming that next birthday is in next year. this is not always true

Comment: Yeah it is true, sorry

Comment: @FerhatBAŞ Thank you. What if I also want to count total days, hours, minutes and seconds I have been alive for ?

Comment: Just change diff variable like this var diff = today-birthday; but you should be careful about month index, I didn't change your birthday calculation "var birthday = new Date(myYear, myMonth, myDay);" this gives to you one more moth.

Answer (score -2):

So you're trying get the days, hours, minutes, and seconds until my next birthday. The problem is you are basing your equation on too little information. Here's the problem.

```
var years = today.getFullYear() - birthday.getFullYear();
//with example values: 30 = 2017 - 1987

//Here you try to get values from 30
var seconds = Math.floor( (years/1000) % 60 );
var minutes = Math.floor( (years/1000/60) % 60 );
var hours = Math.floor( (years/(1000*60*60) ) % 24 );
var days = Math.floor( years/(1000*60*60*24) );
```

The trouble is that Date.prototype.getFullYear() only returns the year, so subtracting one 'fullYear' from another just gives you your age, but doesn't return any other information. To get the results you want you need to find some way to pass on a little more information. My suggestion would be to add something like the following.

```
var years = today.getFullYear() - birthday.getFullYear();

//Edit: it's been pointed out that not everyone's next birthday is next year. This solution still works, but we need to add conditional logic to this next statement.
if ( today.getMonth() > birthday.getMonth() || (today.getMonth() === birthday.getMonth() && today.getDay() >= birthday.getDay() )) {
   var nextYear = today.getFullYear()+1;
}

var nextBirthday = birthday;
nextBirthday.setFullYear(nextYear);

//This converts nextBithday into milliseconds since 1970. Use Date.getTime() to do the same to today and subtract.
var timeToNextBday = nextBirthday - today.getTime();

//From here use math to get the precise days and time until your next birthday
```

Comment: you are assuming that next birthday is in next year. this is not always true

Comment: Hmm, I suppose you're right! Mine is so I didn't think it through any further. This is fixed with a conditional statement "if today's month > bday month, add a year". And similar for days.