# Record Cell Value Time

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to find away to record the amount of time a cell has a specific value. 
example: If H4 = ABC and then change to XYZ; I need to record the amount of time cell H4 was ABC before it was changed to XYZ. 
I have not been able to locate a timer function in the Google script library. 
Any help would be appreciated. 
Here is the link to the sheet and all the scripts currently running. 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eqOXVR9_2fe246PejvwUZd-Z1RoDN8OyS9B7Hk8FZRI/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about a timer function in GAS either and anyway it wouldn't be optimal to have it running all the time. A better way seems to be to calculate time difference on cell change between the timestamp that you have and current date.

I've tweaked [this function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30815312/3555636) a bit so that it also includes difference in hours:

```
function dateDiff(start, end) {
  var diff = { years: 0, months: 0, days: 0 };
  var timeDiff = end - start;

  if (timeDiff > 0) {
    diff.years = end.getFullYear() - start.getFullYear();
    diff.months = end.getMonth() - start.getMonth();
    diff.days = end.getDate() - start.getDate();
    diff.hours = end.getHours() - start.getHours();
    if (diff.months < 0) {
      diff.years--;
      diff.months += 12;
    }

    if (diff.days < 0) {
      diff.months = Math.max(0, diff.months - 1);
      diff.days += 30;
    }
    if (diff.hours < 0) {
      diff.days = Math.max(0, diff.days - 1);
      diff.hours += 24;
    }

  }

  return diff;
};
```

And your `onEdit` function that now uses this dateDiff function:

```
function onEdit() {
  // This section returns if you're not on the SBC/HP spreadsheet.
  var sheet = "SBC/HP";

  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var r = s.getActiveCell();
  // if r is in column h { do the rest }
  if( r.getColumn() != 11){
    var row = r.getRow();
    var previousDate = new Date(s.getRange(row, 11).getValue()); //getting the timestamp of the previous change. Looks like the year should be YYYY, not YY as it is now
    var time = new Date();
    var timeDiff = dateDiff(previousDate, time); //calculating time difference in a separate function
    time = Utilities.formatDate(time, "GMT-05:00", "MM/dd/yy, hh:mm:ss");
    s.getRange(row, 12).setValue(timeDiff.years + ' years ' + timeDiff.months + ' months ' + timeDiff.days + ' days ' + timeDiff.hours + ' hours'); //pasting time difference in some format in a separate cell
    s.getRange('K' + row.toString()).setValue(time);
  }
}
```

You can check how it works [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1A5Ph0fmlmPT41aIZR-4f4oOgXinpc8bKqD29xT_sdqw/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: a-change, Sorry for getting back so late but this worked out quite well. I only made a few changes to the time format to only include days, hours, and minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Combine [Stackdriver Logging](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/logging#stackdriver_logging) with [onEdit()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit). Then use [Log Filters](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/advanced_filters) and/or [Log Exporting](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/configure_export_v2) to extract the timestamps of the INFO log.

```
function onEdit (e) {
  var message = e.range.getA1Notation() + " changed to " + e.value;

  console.info({message:message});
}
```

Get to that projects [Log Viewer](https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer) `View > Stackdriver Logging` in the script editor. From here you can filter out the [console.info()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/console) messages and get the time difference from the timestamps containing the same `e.range.getA1Notation()` in the [Stackdriver Logging](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/logging#stackdriver_logging) message.

[Stackdriver Docs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/)