# Finding number of days between two dates in javascript/redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

```
    let oneDay = 24*60*60*1000;
    let firstDate = new Date();
    let secondDate = this.props.eventData.date
    let finalSecDate = new Date(secondDate)
    var timeDiff = Math.abs(firstDate.getTime() - finalSecDate.getTime());
    var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
```

I am trying to calculate the number of days between two dates using javascript in a redux project. (My second date variable above is based on the date that a user enters and then I am changing it into a new Date format.) The above code works but when the event has passed the the number of days until the event is still coming up as positive number of days. Can someone please help me distinguish whether or not the date has passed so I can get the negative number of days.

I appreciate any help you can give, thank you !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between two dates in years, months, days in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17732897/difference-between-two-dates-in-years-months-days-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/use-it/), since they have a number of date functions that will become useful as you play around with dates more.

Here's what it would look like if you wanted to find the difference between two dates:

```
var present = moment();
var end = this.props.eventData.date;
present.diff(end, 'days') // 5
```

The diff function finds the difference between the two dates. It also solves your problem of returning a negative value if the date already passed.

```
var present = moment();
var past = moment('2014-02-03 12:53:12');
past.diff(present, 'days') // -1379
```