# How can I convert a date into a string called just now; x minutes ago; x days ago, x weeks ago, x years ago etc

Tags: jquery, date

On youtube you often don't get the actual upload date, it just says

```
uploaded x ys ago
```

so how can I achieve this in javascript? Just generate a friendly string from a date?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between two dates in years, months, days in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17732897/difference-between-two-dates-in-years-months-days-in-javascript)

Comment: in my defense, this is hard to search for

Comment: Posting a duplicate is not a bad thing, nor is accepting that your question is a duplicate. Duplicates help people who use the same terms as you have find the same answer.

Comment: oh okay then, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/fromnow/)

```
moment("20120620", "YYYYMMDD").fromNow();
```

Result will be:

> 7 years ago

Answer (score 0):

Just stole this from https://www.w3resource.com/javascript-exercises/javascript-date-exercise-49.php but this looks like what you are looking for

```
function diff_years(dt2, dt1) 
 {

  var diff =(dt2.getTime() - dt1.getTime()) / 1000;
   diff /= (60 * 60 * 24);
  return Math.abs(Math.round(diff/365.25));

 }

dt1 = new Date(2014,10,2);
dt2 = new Date(2014,10,11);
console.log(diff_years(dt1, dt2));

dt1 = new Date("June 13, 2014 08:11:00");
dt2 = new Date("October 19, 2017 11:13:00");
console.log("uploaded " + diff_years(dt1, dt2));
```

Comment: Dude above me looks like he has an easier way actually