# Luxon interval human readable

Tags: javascript, luxon

Hi I would like to express a luxon interval in a localized human-readable manner (Eg. 9 days, 3 hours).

I have achieved this starting from present moment. With this code:

```
DateTime.fromISO(value).toRelative({ locale: "es" });
```

But I cannot achieve the same using neither the Interval o the Duration objects.

This get's the job done. But is not really localization.

```
    const start = DateTime.fromSQL("2020-06-19 11:14:00");
    const finish = DateTime.fromSQL("2020-06-21 13:11:00");

    const {days, hours, minutes} = Interval
        .fromDateTimes(start, finish, {locale: "es"})
        .toDuration(["days", "hours", "minutes"]).values;
    
    console.log(
        `${days ? days + " días " : ""} ${hours ? hours + " horas" : ""} ${
            minutes ? minutes + " minutos." : ""
        }`
    );
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Duration [haven't any analogues of `humanize()` method](https://github.com/moment/luxon/issues/687), so you should use a third-party library. For example, [`humanize-duration`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/humanize-duration), with multilanguage support.

```js
const DateTime = luxon.DateTime;
const Interval = luxon.Interval;

const start = DateTime.fromSQL("2020-06-19 11:14:00");
const finish = DateTime.fromSQL("2020-06-21 13:11:00");

const formatted = Interval
    .fromDateTimes(start, finish)
    .toDuration()
    .valueOf();

console.log(humanizeDuration(formatted))
console.log(humanizeDuration(formatted, { language: 'es' }))
console.log(humanizeDuration(formatted, { language: 'ru' }))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/luxon@1.25.0/build/global/luxon.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/humanize-duration@3.25.1/humanize-duration.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: how do I implement this in angular?