# Rails find difference between two dates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to calculate how long the user has been a member of my app. I should display it as:

`User member for 2y, 9m`

To do so I've created method inside of User model

```
  def member_for
    #calculate number of months
    month = (Time.current.year * 12 + Time.current.month) - (created_at.year * 12 + created_at.month)
    #an array [years, months]
    result = month.divmod(12)

    if result[0].zero? && result[1].nonzero?
      "User member for #{result[1]}m"
    elsif result[1].zero? && result[0].nonzero?
      "User member for #{result[0]}y"
    elsif result[0].zero? && result[1].zero?
      'User member for 1m'
    else
      "User member for #{result[0]}y, #{result[1]}m"
    end
  end
```

But honestly this code smells, isn't there some built-in method in Rails6 to do this better and make the code look a little cleaner?

Comment: You might want to check out the [distance_of_time_in_words](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-distance_of_time_in_words) helper method:

Answer (score 5):

You can use [ActiveSupport::Duration](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.1/classes/ActiveSupport/Duration.html) for this. All you need to do is pass the time difference to the `ActiveSupport::Duration.build` method.
For example:

```
time_diff = Time.now - 1000.days.ago
ActiveSupport::Duration.build(time_diff.to_i)         # 2 years, 8 months, 3 weeks, 5 days, 28 minutes, and 47 seconds 
ActiveSupport::Duration.build(time_diff.to_i).parts   # 2 years, 8 months, 3 weeks, 5 days, 28 minutes, and 47 seconds
```

Comment: Won't 'Time.now - created_at' give the time difference?

Comment: yes it will. You still need write a formatting method though to get something more succint.

Comment: I am not supposed to write the exact code for the problem. I guess the suggestion I gave should have been helpful and the author can move forward with that and add logic around that if he finds it useful.

Comment: This solution leads to the same ifology I wrote. The only difference is that I will have to operate on a hash instead of an array.

Comment: Yes, but this is a built-in method that needs small processing for your use case. You don't have to write an internal method that does almost the same as what this method does.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid [the caching](https://nithinbekal.com/posts/rails-timeago/)/[timezone headaches](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/its-about-time-zones) involved with [`distance_of_time_in_words`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.3.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-distance_of_time_in_words)* which will essentially invalidate your cached responses/fragments continously then just output a HTML5 time element and use a JS library like [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) to calculate the elapsed time and display it to the user:

```
module TimeHelper
  def time_tag(date_or_time, **options)
    tag.time(datetime: date_or_time.iso8601, **options)
  end
end
```

```
$ yarn install moment
```

```
// app/javascripts/packs/application.js
require('moment');
```

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <p><%= time_tag(user.created_at, class: 'member-since') %></p>
<% end %>
```

```js
document.querySelectorAll('time.member-since').forEach((el) => {
  const m = moment(el.dateTime); 
  const str = `User has been a member for ${m.toNow(true)}`;
  const textnode = document.createTextNode(str);
  el.appendChild(textnode);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js" integrity="sha512-qTXRIMyZIFb8iQcfjXWCO8+M5Tbc38Qi5WzdPOYZHIlZpzBHG3L3by84BBBOiRGiEb7KKtAOAs5qYdUiZiQNNQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<p><time datetime="2001-05-15T19:00" class="member-since" /></p>
<p><time datetime="2005-05-15T09:00" class="member-since" /></p>
<p><time datetime="2021-04-15T09:00" class="member-since" /></p>
```

See [Difference between two dates in years, months, days in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17732897/difference-between-two-dates-in-years-months-days-in-javascript) for alternatives to moment.js.

Comment: * This really applies no matter how you output the time on the server side.

Comment: So the answer to how do to solve this basic coding issue in Ruby is go find another language. I mean you're right, it just hurts.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few succint solutions:

```
# In a view helper
def member_for(user)
  "User member for #{distance_of_time_in_words_to_now(user.created_at)}" 
end

# In a controller
def member_for 
  "User member for #{helpers.distance_of_time_in_words_to_now(@user.created_at)}" 
end

# In a model
def member_for 
  "User member for #{ApplicationController.helpers.distance_of_time_in_words_to_now(created_at)}" 
end
```

You could also place this in the view and skip the method:

```
<%= "User member for #{distance_of_time_in_words_to_now(@user.created_at)}" %>
```