# Why won't JavaScript code calculate months between two HTML date time inputs?

Tags: javascript, html, date, input, user-input

I'm trying to calculate the number of months between two HTML date time inputs.

This means the expected result is when the user selects 7/21/21 from the dropdown calendar as a start date and 8/21/21 as an end date then it would be one month.

My actual results are not displayed on the screen.

I didn't get any error messages so I don't know what to fix.

I tried calculating the month difference between two dates by using `Date.parse().value` on the start date (`movein-input`) and the end date (`moveout-input`) and calculating the time apart in milliseconds(ms), minute, hour, day, month, year, years, months, days, and hours but it did work. I found the idea on youtube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q3oiSwdGAq8) and w3schools (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parse.asp).
W3schools said when you display a date object in HTML, it is automatically converted to a string so I thought I could use the html date input in `Date.Parse().value`.

This is my JavaScript code

```
function calculatePrice() {
  let d1 = document.getElementById("movein-input").value;
  let d2 = document.getElementById("moveout-input").value;

  let msBetweenD1And1970 = Date.parse(d1);
  let msBetweenD2And1970 = Date.parse(d2);
  let timeInMs = msBetweenD2And1970-msBetweenD1And1970;

  let ms = timeInMs;
  let second = 1000;
  let minute = second*60;
  let hour = minute*60;
  let day = hour*24;
  let month = day*30;
  let year = day*365;

  let years = Math.round(ms/year);
  let months = years*12;


  var t1 = "That is : "+months;

  document.getElementById("m").innerHTML=t1
}
```

I also have the html code

```
<h2><span id="m">$</span></h2>
```

Calculate price is in the button

```
        <button onclick="calculatePrice()">Enter</button>
```

Comment: Also a small JS note: do not use `.innerHTML` if you're setting text. Use `.textContent`

Comment: how is calculatePrice called? Is there an error in the console? What happens?

Comment: Note that if `movein-input` is an `<input type="date">`, this should be fine. If it's `<input type="text">`, you may have issues. See [Why does Date.parse() return incorrect results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)

Comment: It certainly is, so just comment with that instead next time. The [code of conduct](/conduct) was added a while back exactly in the hopes to prevent these kinds of comments. Instead of telling someone their choice in website was a mistake, leaving them to feel bad about doing what any beginner would do, tell them why, and what you'd recommend they use instead.

Comment: @Kinglish The OP defined a month as 30 days in their code.

Comment: @Kinglish the expected output is 1 month

Comment: @epascarello calculatePrice is called in the button. I've pasted it to the question.

Comment: `<button type="button"`

Comment: See [*Difference between two dates in years, months, days in JavaScript*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17732897/difference-between-two-dates-in-years-months-days-in-javascript?r=SearchResults&s=1|277.3388).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were multiplying when you needed to be dividing.

```
let months = Math.round(ms / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24 / 30)
```

```js
function calculatePrice() {
  let d1 = document.getElementById("movein-input").value;
  let d2 = document.getElementById("moveout-input").value;

  let msBetweenD1And1970 = Date.parse(d1);
  let msBetweenD2And1970 = Date.parse(d2);
  let timeInMs = msBetweenD2And1970-msBetweenD1And1970;

  let ms = timeInMs;
  let months = Math.round(ms / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24 / 30)
 
  var t1 = `That is ${months} months`;

  document.getElementById("m").textContent=t1
}
```

```html
<h2><span id="m">$</span></h2>

<input type='date' id='movein-input' value='2021-03-01' />
<input type='date' id='moveout-input' value='2021-06-01' />
<button onclick='calculatePrice()'>calculate</button>
```