# Get difference of two dates in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date, google-analytics

I have two dates in YYYY-MM-DD format.
I want to subtract the dates and get the integer value of two numbers between them.

If I have:

```
var startDate = "2014-09-25";
var endDate = "2014-10-12";
```

I would want the difference to be 18 days. I was planning on putting it in my Google Analytics, so it could look like this:

```
query: {
    ...
    start-date: "18daysAgo",
    end-date: "today"
}
```

How would I go about this?

Comment: are you trying to turn "2014-10-12" into "18daysAgo" ? that will be hard.

Comment: @GrahamS. Easy way to do it look below.

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41948/how-do-i-get-the-difference-between-two-dates-in-javascript

Comment: I'm more or less trying to just get the integer value and then concatenating it to the string, for e.g. `numOfDays + "daysAgo"`.

Comment: Look at the answer below. @GrahamS.

Comment: analytics-api supports both these formats, so why do you need to convert them yourself? https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#startDate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can do it:

```
var aDay = 24*60*60*1000; // hours*minutes*seconds*milliseconds
var date1 = new Date(2014, 09, 25);
var date2 = new Date(2014, 10, 12);

var diffDays = Math.round(Math.abs((date1.getTime() - date2.getTime())/(aDay)));

window.alert("" + diffDays);
```

This will give you the number of days between 2 dates.

Comment: Tried this. I keep getting `1` as my answer for the dates `2014-10-12` and `2014-09-30` (Those are the dates I'm testing right now.)

Comment: i deleted the comment harping on your typo, and the one about the time of day. i realized that since you are always producing a local midnight date by being unspecific about timezones, it should balance out, which is not the case if you were parsing dates. crude write-up and over-zealous commenting aside, it's not a bad answer... oh, and i promise you can subtract dates, that's one you need to try ;)

Comment: @dandavis I know you can subtract dates but it won't give him the answer he is looking for (number of days between 2 dates) that was what I meant when I said it wouldn't work.  It's alright though no hard feelings I will delete my other comments so there is not as much overhead with this answer.  I should have worded my comments a little differently I was just frustrated because you were saying this doesn't work when it does and it is a solution to his problem without using external libraries (maybe try the solution before saying it doesn't work).

Comment: @dandavis That being said I shouldn't have made some of the comments I did.