# NaN javascript error when calculating between dates with timestamp

Tags: javascript

I would like to begin by saying i looked at multiple threads in this forum before posting. Wasnt able to find my solution :(

**Issue:** getting a NaN error when trying to find the difference between two dates with a timestamp from two textboxes.

The date format i'm using is DDMMYYYY HH:MM - 27/01/2015 00:00
code below.

thank you in advance for this super helpful forum :)

```
function stringToDate(s) {
    var dateParts = s.split(' ')[0].split('-'); 
    var timeParts = s.split(' ')[1].split(':');
    var d = new Date(dateParts[0], --dateParts[1], dateParts[2]);
    d.setHours(timeParts[0], timeParts[1], timeParts[2]);

    return d;
}

function test() {
    var a = textbox_1.value;
    var b = textbox_2.value;
    alert(stringToDate(a) - stringToDate(b));
}
```

Comment: I click a button and call test()

Answer (score 1):

Your date has `/` as separator but you are splitting the string on `-`. Change

```
var dateParts = s.split(' ')[0].split('-');
```

to

```
var dateParts = s.split(' ')[0].split('/');
```

Also, your time part has only hours and minutes, so there is no `timeParts[2]` present, just remove it from the `setHours()` call. Like this:

```
d.setHours(timeParts[0], timeParts[1])
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/2evj59d1/

**EDIT**
Your code returns the difference in milliseconds. To convert it into date format just change

```
alert(stringToDate(a) - stringToDate(b));
```

to

```
alert(new Date(stringToDate(a) - stringToDate(b)));
```

Comment: thank you for your response. I tried the code with begin/end dates as 27/01/2015 00:00 and 27/01/2015 00:01 respectively. the result i get is 60000. I dont know what to make of it.

Comment: @marv: The response is in milliseconds. 60000 milliseconds = 60 seconds = 1 minute.

Comment: yikes, that was dumb of me. so sorry. thank you so much for your help mate. I really appreciate it!!

Comment: Thanks again. I tested and its working fine. sorry one more thing i missed. This doesn't calculate the date based on the hours. I tried 02/03/2015 18:26 - 30/01/2015 18:23 returned 3.0 minutes which is correct. It should say 1.03 ( 1 day 3 minutes). sorry completely forgot i also needed help excluding weekend calculation

Comment: EDIT: I tried 29/01/2015 20:26 - 29/01/2015 20:25, and get 4:1. The one minute is correct, but the days are incorrect. Any clue?
I'm using this code to convert to milliseconds:

Answer (score 0):

The code is trying to parse a time in the format `HH:MM:SS`. Skip the third part:

```
d.setHours(timeParts[0], timeParts[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the date into milliseconds, get the difference and get the date back.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wrejhvhp/1/)

JSCode:

```
var a = new Date();
a.setDate(15);
a = a.getTime();
var b = new Date();
b.setDate(32);
b = b.getTime();
var c = b - a;
var date = new Date(c);
alert(date.getDate() - 1);
```

Comment: thank you for your response. I tried your code and it appears to give me the correct result. this may be a simple question - how do i tweak the code to reference the textbox date values?

Answer (score 0):

for those who may have stumbled upon my post, i found my answer at the link below by user benjour.
[How do I get the difference between two Dates in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41948/how-do-i-get-the-difference-between-two-dates-in-javascript)