# How to subtract time and date

Tags: java, date

I have an ArrayList that has times and dates added like so

```
06/18/2015 12:25
06/19/2015 22:45
```

I want to know how can i get the exact time difference in hours between each both date. I have tried

```
long diff = Math.abs(d1.getTime() - d2.getTime());
long diffDays = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
```

Comment: Seems to be duplicate: 
http://stackoverflow.com/q/41948/2814475

Comment: @Peszo No sorry thats a different issue mine has time and date in the one row they just have date