# Conditional Alert in HTML Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, date

I have managed to automatically build an HTML table based on a output from my ERP system, and managed to use CSS to format it easily.  The last step is conditional formatting in a Date Field.  If the date is <  from now make the field RED if it's between 4 <> 7 days from NOW make it YELLOW  else "no formatting.

I have gotten this far on dozens of examples from this site, and I am hoping you can help me do some basic DATE MATH which for some reason I just can't get my head around.

Right now my date field is in  the td:nth-child(4) and I want to compaire it to the current date.

```
    <script>

    $(document).ready(function() {

            $('table td:nth-child(4)').each(function() {
                var D1 = $(this).text();
                var D2 = new Date();

                if ((D1 - D2) < 4) {
                    $(this).css('backgroundColor', 'RED'); 
                }
                else if((D1 - D2) < 7) && ((D1 - D2) > 4) {
                    $(this).css('backgroundColor', 'YELLOW'); 
                }
                else {
                    $(this).css('backgroundColor', '#99faa0'); 
                }

            });
            event.preventDefault();
    });

    </script>
```

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41948/how-do-i-get-the-difference-between-two-dates-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert and compare the dates properly. Below is the example to compare dates.

Reference:

[Get difference between 2 dates in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224834/get-difference-between-2-dates-in-javascript)

```
var _MS_PER_DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;

// a and b are javascript Date objects
function dateDiffInDays(a, b) {
  // Discard the time and time-zone information.
  var utc1 = Date.UTC(a.getFullYear(), a.getMonth(), a.getDate());
  var utc2 = Date.UTC(b.getFullYear(), b.getMonth(), b.getDate());
  return Math.floor((utc2 - utc1) / _MS_PER_DAY);
}
```

**Working sample**

https://jsfiddle.net/zsLfh3kj/1/

Comment: If you find a question that has already been asked, please flag the question as a duplicate of the question you've found. Please do not answer it.

Comment: Thank you.  Between this and the other links I was able to figure it out.