# Format the time from moment js

Tags: node.js, vue.js, momentjs

When I am trying to receive mail from gmail, I get time in this format (`Mon, 12 Jun 2017 10:29:07 +0530`). I want to calculate time minus current time. How to do so?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the difference between two Dates in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41948/how-do-i-get-the-difference-between-two-dates-in-javascript)

Comment: Your question doesn't show any research effort, nor are you clear about what output you are looking for.  Show what you have tried, what you got, what you expected, etc.  Also, this has nothing to do with `vue.js`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var testDate = moment("Mon, 12 Jun 2017 10:29:07 +0530");

//Relative to time in human readble format
testDate.fromNow(); //3 days ago
```

Comment: How to convert this into like if less than a min then only sec . if less than an hour then only min , if less than day then only hr

Comment: Have updated answer to show a human readable format of the same. Probably what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply call the moment constructor with the given Date format. moment.js is smart enough to parse it for you. To get the difference you can convert it into unix based time format and subtract it.

```
const givenTime = moment("Mon, 12 Jun 2017 10:29:07 +0530").unix()
const currentTime = moment().unix()
//Difference in milliseconds
const diff = givenTime - currentTime
```

Comment: How to convert this into like if less than a min then only sec . if less than an hour then only min , if less than day then only hr

Comment: can u write it for me ?

Comment: Please try it yourself first :) and if you don't get the answer then post on the stack overflow again.