# How to do calculation of this statement

Tags: javascript

how to do the calculation of this statement

```
var dateTo = new Date(2019,04,03,3,15,0);
var countdown = Math.round((dateTo.getTime() - new Date().getTime()) / 1000);
```

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: The expected output is remaining time

Comment: Explain the expected behavior and any of your assumptions

Comment: current date minus provided date

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the difference between two Dates in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41948/how-do-i-get-the-difference-between-two-dates-in-javascript)

Comment: You just hand it to any JavaScript interpreter, e.g. your browser.

Answer (score 0):

Is the value not what you expected?
Try to print the date and make sure the value is what you wanted:

```
var dateTo = new Date(2019,04,03,3,15,0);
console.log(dateTo);
```

Also it is better to use only 4 and 3 instead of "04" and "03".

Answer (score 0):

is this what you're going for?

```
#// Set the date we're counting down to
    var countDownDate = new Date("Jan 5, 2021 15:37:25").getTime();

  // Get todays date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();

  // Find the distance between now and the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;

  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));


  console.warn("val", days);
```