# How do I subtract date from today's date in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, math

The logic I want to display is:

```
{transfusions.map((transfusion) => {
          return (
            <tr key={transfusion.id} className="shadow-lg">
              <th scope="row">{transfusion.id}</th>
              <td>{transfusion.donor}</td>
              <td>{transfusion.blood_component}</td>
              <td>{transfusion.unit}</td>
              <td>{transfusion.created_at}</td>
              <td>
                <i
                  className="fas fa-edit"
                  onClick={() => handleUpdate(transfusion)}
                ></i>{" "}
                <i
                  className="fas fa-trash pl-1"
                  onClick={() =>
                    window.confirm(
                      "Are you sure you wish to delete this transfusion?"
                    ) && deleteTransfusion(transfusion.id)
                  }
                ></i>
              </td>
            </tr>
```

**created_at date** is displaying as this format `2020-07-15T13:29:15.524486Z`

So I want to subtract the current/today's date which is like this format `Wed Jul 22 2020 10:57:59 GMT+0300 (East Africa Time)`

and finally display the number of days between these dates which is like integer number **13**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the difference between two Dates in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41948/how-do-i-get-the-difference-between-two-dates-in-javascript)

Comment: no bro and thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: And why not? While the accepted answer is not really useful, the second most voted one does exactly what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15810692/7916438

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const daysBetween = new Date().getDate() - new Date('2020-07-15T13:29:15.524486Z').getDate()
```

Comment: Thanks. This answer really helped me with my issue. Thanks again.

Comment: @AhmadEbrahim this answer is wrong. `getDate()` simply returns the day part of a date. Try it with a couple dates from June for example.

Comment: yea you're right, it would not work as intended. The solution @laruiss gave coupled with your comment would give the correct result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Date` constructor:

```
const currentDate = new Date('Wed Jul 22 2020 10:57:59 GMT+0300 (East Africa Time)')
const oldDate = new Date('2020-07-15T13:29:15.524486Z')
currentDate - oldDate // 584923476
```

To display the duration, you can either use [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/v2.15.0/docs/formatDuration), [luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/class/src/duration.js%7EDuration.html), [moment](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/) or [Temporal](https://tc39.es/proposal-temporal/docs/cookbook.html#unit-constrained-duration-between-now-and-a-pastfuture-zoned-event)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. can you convert me these numbers 584923476 into understandable numbers like 20days, 46, days, 855day?

Comment: @AhmadEbrahim that number is expressed in milliseconds. In order to have days, divide it by `(1000*60*60*24)`.